# Should we delete "What's the best C++ JSON parser?"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, locked-posts

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245973/792066) on the site, which is off topic, locked, and obsolete which apparently [can cause problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280826/792066). Should we just delete it?

Lets asses the value of the post from a quantitative point of view:

First of all, it doesn't have all the options: JsonCpp twice, JSON Spirit twice, Boost's `property_tree` (not a dedicated library, but whatever), Jansson, `UniversalContainer` class (?), yajl (not strictly C++ but C, *shrugs*). 6 solutions in total. The official JSON page includes 17 libraries, all of the above already included. Obviously, json.org has the most complete list. So, the internet isn't losing anything in terms of "amount of solutions available".

From a qualitative point of view:

I know it has a note that says that "these kind of questions are not good fit for the site, blablabla" (paraphrased) but, if it's not-a-good-fit, isn't it more desirable that we just get rid of it, specially if a most complete set is available elsewhere?

Anyone wants to share their views about what's more beneficial for Stack Overflow and the internet in this specific aspect?

Comment: For the record: [I locked that question to prevent people from deleting it so that you can still find an answer. –  Bill the Lizard♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132421)

Comment: The answers don't add anything of value anyway. The question asks "**would like some feedback on which parser people prefer - for reliability, speed and ease of use.**" and they barely manage to do that.

Comment: Also for the record: If there are better answers that are readily available via Google search, I'm fine with removing the lock and deleting that question. Locks don't necessarily need to be permanent. If clicking a Stack Overflow link is wasting people's time in their search for an answer, we should remove that entry from the search results.

Comment: Now it should be deleted to prevent folks from [ranting about Bill the Lizard locking posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280826/why-does-bill-the-lizard-lock-all-the-good-questions)

Comment: Yes because locking a post == censorship.

Comment: how dare you lock a post to not have it removed! I hope you're ashamed of censoring us so we CAN see information..... wait..... what?

Comment: Questions like this might be useful sometimes, but they should not have a *historical* lock because it prevents them from updating (the information there are getting old with no way to fix).

Comment: Consider this: If you delete this answer, some people will suddenly loose a big share of their rep. Not sure it's a good idea - wouldn't people be more reluctant to contribute answers knowing they may be deleted in the future just because they're old?

Comment: @Lucas Well it is the future now. And the top answerer only has 6 answers and 1 question, one of the answers being 91 upvotes which overshadows the others. And it is on a poll question which is considered off topic by today's standards. So the user wouldn't be losing much as they aren't an active contributor, and if they were, it's likely that they'd be aware of how the site handle things nowadays.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - No [deletion of highly voted historic answers doesn't affect rep](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) "if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,

A score of 3 or greater
Visible on the site for at least 60 days"

Comment: Can we also delete [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739622/best-c-library-to-encode-or-decode-json?lq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016503/what-is-the-popular-json-c-library?lq=1) then, please?

Comment: @lpapp - But not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13095749/73226)? it is currently closed as a dupe of the locked one.

Comment: @MartinSmith: once my delete votes are back, I will cast a delete vote on each of those. [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575077/c-json-parsers-research) to go. Gah, [more to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070856/how-to-parse-json-in-c). [Another beauty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538725/is-there-a-c-library-to-read-json-documents-into-c-objects).

Comment: *rubs @lpapp wound with [a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/245973?lq=1)*

Comment: @remyabel I know these users are inactive, but I was talking in a broader sense. I wasn't aware of the *worthwhile contribution* rule, but I'm glad it exists. a *future* policy change shouldn't impact your *past* contributions, and that was the point of my comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to what [remyabel explained in their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280842), I'm also deleting this question based on my personal experiences when looking for software on Google.

If someone wanted a list of various JSON parsers with no real information about how it works or what makes it better than others, they could easily get that list from [json.org](http://json.org) at the bottom of the page. That's generally *not* what people want, though. People want *recommendations*. They want to know which ones work best, most reliably, most efficiently. This question does not provide *any* of that. It's just another list, like any other.

As far as my personal experience, seeing a top result like this, which *explicitly asks* which one is the best, following that link, and just finding another list of crap that doesn't explain anything **is the most frustrating thing a user can encounter on Google**. It's a complete waste of time and does not at all help decide on what to use. There's nothing worse than seeing a great title on a respected site only to follow it and have your hopes crushed by some crappy content that's "historical" and won't be deleted.

Comment: Well, that settled it. Wanna go through [this other *list*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/245973?lq=1).

Comment: @Braiam - The ones closed as dupe on that list have already gone I think.

Comment: Ohh! *goes and blame catching*

Comment: Now we wait for someone to post a rant asking why animuson deletes all the posts...

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Oh people already do that.

Comment: @Braiam: I am going to spend my dupehammer on some of them, I think.

Comment: [BillLizard is the big locker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier). :)

Comment: It's good to see someone who acknowledges that software recommendation questions can be useful when asked right, and not have close votes sent to it the next second.

Answer (score 9):

In general, we want people to see StackOverflow as the first result when they Google something. And we also want the questions that people see to set a good example for future visitors. If the post was not locked, it would not be clear to the uninitiated that this type of question is considered off topic.

However you've already demonstrated that the question has little redeeming value. The recommendations by the answerers are very short and and the list of libraries are incomplete compared to the [official website](http://www.json.org/). If people were looking for an authoritative and complete list of recommendations, they should see that rather than the question. If the question is deleted, then it will disappear from the search results and no longer be a distraction. On the other hand, poll questions can have redeeming value if the answers are good, but in this case they're not. For example the top answer states:

> I looked at most of them a year or so ago, and settled on JsonCpp
> (http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/).
> I've found it reliable, fast and easy to use, so 3/3.

This is a completely useless answer. The comments (which were posted years later) lament issues with the library, which means that those who follow the recommendation might be irritated by being falsely led. And the answer can't be edited because the post has been locked.

As stated in the comments, the answerers won't lose reputation because they fit the criteria of a "worthwhile" answer ([Deleted posts should not influence reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation), 
[Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)). Even if they *did* lose reputation, my argument for that is it wouldn't make a difference because:

- In example, the top answerer is not an active contributor with only 6 answers and 1 question. They probably wouldn't care if a useless answer they posted 6 years ago was removed (and in fact it's expected. Things disappear on the Internet all the time.)
- If they were an active contributor, they'd probably be aware of modern site policies.

So yes, the post should probably be deleted.