# Highly scored recommendation with pending delete votes - how to save?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606/what-free-software-can-i-use-to-create-ui-mockups is currently at +79 score with over 60k views. It was asked back in '08 when things where a bit different.  It has been closed since April 2013 and last active a year ago (there is no apparent community desire to maintain the existing answers).

The quality of the majority of the answers... lets say "poor" to be charitable.

Because there is a desire to maintain any answers that have useful material, how should this question be saved?

- Does someone who feels that this question have merit and remain (I don't believe this is the case) want to try to make a community wiki post out of the accepted answer, flag for a mod to make it into community wiki and delete all the other posts?
- Should it just be deleted?
- Should it be historically locked and forgotten (suggesting that "How about Paint.NET" as an answer is something that should be retained for eternity)
- Do something to try to migrate it to software recs via SE community manager involvement?

  - Maybe migrating the question there, creating a new (non-voted) Q&A on software recs that contains the useful answer material, deleting all the posts in the now migrated post and merging it with the newly created one - this would set up a chain of redirects so that people following the links will get to the proper destination with all the useful information yet without dumping 415 reputation into a beta site.

Noting that any fixing of this question for some sort of preservation of quality (rather just saying "meh - its all historical - preserve the crap too") would take significant mod intervention (marking things as community wiki and deleting other answer posts that have a positive score), would it be more sensible for a mod just to do all the janitorial work on this instead - especially if the mod feels that there is merit in retaining this post?

I wish to point out that we shouldn't be encouraging people posting questions like this now (by having high scoring questions) or answers of the quality that are presented in this post. The continued presence of posts like these sends a message to new users that they are indeed valid and useful posts *here* and new users will continue to post questions and answers that are no better than the worst of these examples.

Comment: I'll note that I didn't actually read all of your question, just looked at the Stack Overflow question. But I have to say, I think it's better to just delete this. There's nothing of lasting value in that question. It's just a massive link dump. Almost all of those answers would be delete-worthy on Software Recommendations.

Comment: Historical locks and the like are there for content that is already of extraordinarily high value.  It's not there to put on crap content in the hope that it might become not crap (which is made all the more difficult given that locked content can't be edited).  When you find an off topic question with no particularly valuable content, delete it.

Comment: @Servy I absolutely agree. However, there seems to be a suggestion in other posts that if any answer contains anything of value or use, the entire question should be saved (the accepted answer has a score of more than +30 and so something something...).  Thus, that's what I'm asking - how should it be saved?

Comment: @MichaelT If the content is *already* of *extraordinarly high* value, there are ways of keeping it from being deleted.  This question (nor any of the answers) is not of very high value.  The fact that an answer has a score of 30 doesn't mean it's of high quality.  In fact, given 60k views, that's an *extraordinarily* low percentage of readers who marked it as useful.

Comment: Those answers (which are pretty much all "link only" LQ answers) aren't really being maintained, and will eventually become irrelevant (I didn't check to see if they _already are_). Delete.

Comment: @animuson may I ask your opinion about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) which has even more views and votes? Realizing the difficulty of regular users to delete the answers such as "Simple XML http://simple.sourceforge.net/ is very easy for (de)serializing objects."

Comment: @Servy it had *more* than +30 (don't recall what it is anymore) which was a threshold mentioned in a comment on another post about trying to hide delete votes for pile on delete voting.

Comment: @MichaelT Okay.  That doesn't mean that the answer wasn't crap, because it was.  The fact that 0.1% of viewers found the just about link only answer helpful doesn't make it a quality answer worth preserving.

Comment: @Servy I'm well aware of that and believe that popularity, especially on an 7 year old question is a very poor indicator of utility. There are others who likely hold the opposite view.  Unfortunately, unless these examples are brought up and discussed on meta and a record established of "no, its crap and has no indication of utility" it becomes difficult to dissuade people of those opinions.

Comment: @MichaelT The existing policies are just what I've repeated here.  If content is already of extraordinarily high value, it can be preserved.  This content is not, so deleting it is appropriate.  That one person in one place that you don't even remember suggested we universally consider all content with 30 votes to be "very high quality" doesn't make that a policy that needs to be reversed.

Comment: @Servy I know [exactly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year/286970#comment160265_286970) where that 30 threshold comment is. And given the activity there, I believe it is important to provide counter examples which include the possibility of "no, it isn't possible to save this material and trying to make this go through more hoops would be counterproductive" on meta.

Comment: @MichaelT One comment by one person brainstorming ideas 20 comments down on a meta post is not policy; it doesn't require a new meta question to try to reverse it.  If you think that thought Tim mentioned when thinking out load was flawed, consider replying to him and informing him of your concerns, rather than just assuming it has already become official policy.

Comment: @Servy also note the suggested policy of "If you see upvoted content that is useful, don't delete." in that question - if the material here is useful, it shouldn't be deleted - the question then is how to save it.  This goes to two points - if the material is useful (what is the threshold for that?) and what do upvotes actually mean on ancient posts. This is an attempt to say "here is an upvoted "useful" post' - lets think about it over here too with more than fits in comments - *how* should we save these posts rather than delete them?

Comment: @MichaelT This content is not upvoted content that is useful, this is upvoted content that isn't useful, so that doesn't apply.  You seem to be conflating upvoted with useful, and they're not the same thing.  Upvotes are an indication that content might be useful, not a guarantee that it is.  If you think that Tim thinks that all upvoted content is useful based on his comment, I can assure you that he doesn't; he's well aware that it's just a signal that the content is more likely to be useful.

Comment: There is no hard and fast number/threshold of upvotes past which content is automatically considered useful.  Votes are one of the many factors that you should take in when evaluating whether or not some content is useful.  It is certainly not the only one.

Answer (score 10):

This is a great example of the problems inherent in software recommendation questions: although the question itself was reasonably well-specified, the answers are...

Well, only two of the answers even meet the requirements outlined in the question. Of the two, the top-voted answer recommends a product that doesn't appear to be maintained and - according to the comments - is no longer working on at least some platforms.

At this point, we're doing folks a disservice by keeping it around: the question is nothing but a pitfall for folks searching, a dead-end at which they'll waste time without coming away with anything useful.

It is now deleted, and it should stay that way.

I'm *very* sympathetic toward communities that create and maintain good references for answering these sorts of questions. I was just commenting to a co-worker earlier today on how happy I am that the [wiki-lock feature is being put to good use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year) to preserve such content. However, we must exercise discretion when evaluating these posts: if they're not kept updated and not helping people, they absolutely must be removed.

Comment: "if they're not kept updated" this part needs to be stressed more. Some times, people don't want the content deleted because, well, they don't want the content deleted, even if it's obsolete, incomplete, or exist better resources somewhere else (as [this example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066)).