# What should I do with my question if I realise it is not useful for the community?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am fairly new to the world of Stack Overflow so I am still learning the community etiquette, I appreciate the importance of good content for the community so I would like some advice on how to improve my questions and what to do with questions that I feel would not benefit the community.

I have asked 5 questions thus far, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555692/why-does-float-work-but-not-int I hold my hands up, I should have done more research so I can appreciate the bad reception.

However, I have asked 2 other questions that I then realized would not be useful to the community (Probably the reason why I struggled to find similar questions). In this question [Why does Dec memory address descend and Hex memory address ascend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215077/why-does-dec-memory-address-descend-and-hex-memory-address-ascend) the answer did help me but I doubt anyone else will find it useful and this question [What is happening when I declare a string as: char aString[SIZE*2+1];?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307075/declaring-a-string-size) I literally realized the answer after I posted the question.

So, to summarise, in an effort to become a better community member, what should I do about useless questions, is it appropriate to delete them?

Comment: All those questions have answers, so no, deletion is now too late or extremely rude if you unaccept the answers and then delete the question. Just hope nobody notices them anymore ... oh wait .. you just brought them under the attention of the not so easy going meta crowd...

Comment: Where your questions are not 'helpful', consider making them more informative and adding references for others who may come along later interested in the same topic.  It doesn't hurt to go back and add information to a question that, in itself, may not be helpful, but by extension, could be.

Comment: Well, you are right.  You can't delete them.  Maybe you can feel better by seeing that a low-rep user knew how to do it properly but didn't yet have the rep to do so.  And a hi-rep user made no attempt to do it properly, boo.  We can help delete the division question but the others are going to get you question-banned if we do it for you.  Live and learn.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful feedback, I will go back and edit my questions, adding what I have learned in the hope it can be helpful for users interested in the topics. Hopefully other members will be forgiving of my mistakes.

Comment: In theory at least, isn't usefulness determined by community voting, rather than the asker?

Comment: I'd say its very brave to claim that no-one ever will find your question useful. If it has an answer, leave it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I respectfully disagree, the questions I had asked were genuine and proved to be very useful to me, formatting and duplicate questions aside, is a question ever useless if at least the person asking the question is able to learn from the answer? The reason for the above question is due to receiving a notification informing me that my past 3 questions had not been received well by the community and that I should take time to reflect on my questions to prevent a question ban, I interpreted this as my content not being useful/helpful.

Comment: @8TrackRobot If you received a notification then I guess that is the voice of the community speaking, albeit in an automated way.  Good luck with your future questions.

Answer (score 22):

If you're pretty much sure your question is unlikely to help future users, and if no answers were already provided, then yes, delete it.

The most important thing (which I personally appreciate), is your willingness to improve your posts, and to be a helpful member in Stack Overflow. So as long as you're learning from your mistakes, you're doing the right thing.

Comment: (which doesn't apply in this case, as the question has answers)

Comment: @user202729 questions with answers has been deleted before because they aren't useful anymore. Case point https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066

Comment: Wait a minute here. Isn't there some mechanism in place punishing users for deleting too much of their posted content? I believe so and I believe it is based on a percentage of total posts by that user. So someone with hundreds of questions/answers won't be affected, but a new user with 30 rep will. Someone please confirm or deny this before we recommend a new user to start deleting their own posts.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369472 Seems to suggest that there are cases where the user will be unable to delete their posts, including if they have upvoted answers

Answer (score 5):

Just forget about your first questions. Doing anything to them marks them as "recently modified" which is just annoying if they're relatively-but-not-completely useless.

---

Remember that questions are only part of the site. You can also answer, or (eventually) comment and review. In any case, you should spend some time looking at other people's answers.

You should *not* attempt to answer every question you see - I find that, even within my preferred tags, only perhaps 1 in 5 questions is both a good-quality question and a question that is truly in my understanding. For a newcomer, likely even fewer questions are answerable.

But in any case, you should *look* at other questions - both to learn what works and what doesn't work for your own, and to contribute to the site in other ways.

Many questions are duplicates, and many answers are link-only or otherwise low-quality. Once you get 15 karma, you can [flag them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) if you're sure they are inappropriate.

You can also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) any question or answer if you think you can significantly improve it. There are a *lot* of questions with poor formatting and many typos - generally more substantial edits are suggested in comments for the original answerer to merge if they want, or else posted as a separate answer (StackOverflow does not require only one correct answer per question, although too much overlap should be avoided and mentioning "building on 's answer:" is nice).

However, **do *not* edit something that cannot be salvaged** - flag it instead.