# Are questions about the motives of programming library developers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, historical-lock

[This question about why libCurl is free](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55884514) has been closed 3 times and removed from the Hot Network Questions by a moderator. It seems to be opinion based:

> What is the incentive for curl to release the library for free?

The developer himself answered, and his answer is really, really good (+500 in one day is quite a feat). Heck, I myself owe him, because I use libCurl myself. That alone, however, doesn't make this a good fit for SO.

Should we allow this type of Q&A on Stack Overflow? Should we just historical lock the question for posterity?

**Note** - This is not about asking [why a programming language does something a certain way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio). This largely revolves around what to do with this specific question and a much narrower instance of someone posting an off-topic question and getting a very serious answer from the source.

Comment: _"Should we just historical lock the question for posterity?"_ Sounds fair.

Comment: agree with @πάνταῥεῖ.  If we don't do something, it is likely going to be the next [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) with respect to the confusion and drama of "why is my question closed when this one is left open"

Comment: It is *not* "primarily opinion-based". There are admittedly a very limited number of people who know the answer to the question, but that doesn't make it opinion-based. It has an objective answer, one which was provided. I've been debating about what to do with that question, but closing it as "primarily opinion-based" was never one of my considered actions. If it is to be closed as anything, that would be "off topic", because it's about aspects of the broader software engineering trade that Stack Overflow does not handle (i.e., licensing, the business of open source, etc.).

Comment: Sometimes it's worth allowing questions like this a historical lock. It's not often when the original author writes a good answer from a library so old and foundational to modern methodology.

Comment: Historical lock presumes that the question was asked in historical times when the question would have been on topic, but now is not. This was asked very recently. Seems like using it for the libCurl question would signal that it's okay to ask these kinds of questions even if they are off topic, as long as someone answers with a highly upvoted answer...

Comment: @SterlingArcher I wish it were that clear cut. That answer is awesome, but the question isn't. Leaving it alone isn't a great option because it invites more of the same. Do we want people openly asking questions like "Why is jQuery free?"

Comment: On the other hand, @HereticMonkey, we *are* [optimizing for pearls, not sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: @CodyGray: It **is** opinion-based. The question is asking for the opinion of a software developer, and the answer is the opinion of a software developer. There is nothing in that question that is not about opinions. Any question asking for the *motivation* of a person is opinion-based.

Comment: delete it and forget about it. The answer isn't really good, it was just shared strategically and found to be interesting (similar to my own answer to (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)). In this case it isn't on topic.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't believe the libCurl question is anything but fool's gold, upvoted only because curl is very popular in the programming community, and people wanted to reward the author for *that* contribution, not necessarily for the Stack Overflow answer as a stunning exemplar.

Comment: With that logic, @Chris, pretty much every question here is asking for the opinion of a software developer. "How do I create a tuple in C++?" ==> "How did the creator of the tuple facility in C++ decide that this feature should be implemented?" The point of the "primarily opinion-based" close reason is to discourage questions that would attract a slew of low-quality answers, like "What is the best Java IDE?". It specifically says in the description that *many* questions involve a degree of opinion; the operative word there is "primarily".

Comment: @HereticMonkey The historical lock wording uses the qualifying phrase "historical significance". Even an ongoing event can qualify for historical significance, thus I don't see an issue with using that lock reason for a question that's so clearly dividing the community but overwhelmingly upvoted (at what is surely a record or near-record pace).

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't agree with your equivalence there. When asking how to do something in C++, we're not asking how Stroustrup envisioned it or why he designed it that way, we're asking how to solve a problem. This question does not do that. It explicitly asks about the motivation for one person's past action.

Comment: @CodyGary I both agree and disagree with you at the same time. You've hit the nail on the head with this question prescribing to the "broader software engineering trade", but I think your reluctance to call this opinion based isn't quite right. He's specifically asking for the "incentive for curl to be free". Asking for an incentive is always going to be opinion based. I believe it is just rare that in this ONE specific case, the creator actually answered. 99% of questions like this would have extremely low quality answers.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907236) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55003330) are better examples. My larger point is that "primarily opinion-based" needs to be used *very* sparingly, and only deployed against questions that are actually causing a problem or where there is very strong evidence that they are going to cause a problem. Not deployed against any and all questions that involve some type of subjectivity. These are the types of questions that prevent this site from becoming a debugging service. @Cris.

Comment: @TylerH The answer on [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587) says, "A good rule of thumb: If the question does not minimally meet Jeff Atwood's 3rd rule in the "We Hate Fun Here" blog post, it's probably not a good candidate for historical locking. The third rule is: Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?" I don't believe that the impetus for libCurl being free helps one do their job better. Can you learn anything from it? Sure, don't ask questions like this on SO :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm just pointing out what the banner language says which is and can be something used as justification for its application. Anyway, regarding your link, the four points of 'where historical locks can be used' all apply to this question. The only one that may not apply is #2, and that point, as it turns out, is a subjective judgment rather than an objective one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The development and delivery philosophy of a founder and maintainer of a (currently) critical library can make people better at their jobs by exposing them to a perspective and approach to work that they can adopt when creating their own projects or contributing to others.  Granted, that may bend the meaning of "make me better at my job" more than intended.  Perhaps it would better fit on some theoretical "Programming Philosophy" StackExchange, but that doesn't exist today.

Comment: The answer makes internet a better place, that should be enough for anyone on SO to look the other way, deleting has no sense @KevinB

Comment: @Rakuen42 Licensing choices have been specifically off topic for Stack Overflow for quite a long time irrespective of whether they are helpful to one's job.

Comment: How exactly does it make the internet a better place? I won't deny that it's popular... but that hardly improves the internet. It will simply be used as justification for others to ask similarly awful questions.

Comment: @KevinB it gives insight about a developer of an import lib and the reasons related to developing open-source. *Used as justification?*, really? While we are commenting we are submerged with "Plz debug this?" and yeah they have provided mcve...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Asking why something is free-of-charge isn't the same as asking about license choice; the concepts are not mutually inclusive.  That said, if we're looking at it strictly as a license choice question then maybe it could move to Open Source which does allow questions about licensing.

Comment: _What is the actual problem?_ I don't buy the *used as justification...* mcve is used as justification to post useless stuff...

Comment: What i have a problem with is it being a historical lock, for a question that is so recent. Not because "history" implies old, but because it implies that questions like this can be asked and answered and highly rewarded, if they're shared with the right crowd, regardless of whether or not they are on topic here and then be immune to removal.

Comment: @KevinB yeah you need to be lucky ask some off-topic stuff about linux and get an answer from Torvalds before it's closed... and then yeah the community will not delete it since we believe "making internet a better place" is more important then some unfounded fears about *Used as justification*

Comment: @PetterFriberg It isn't useful information that a developer 2 years from now will look back on and say "Hey, that solved my problem!" it's simply trivia, better left for sites like medium, reddit, or blogs. I'm not going to debate with you about MCVE and debug this for me garbage, as I believe we mostly align there.

Comment: @KevinB yeah it's heavily off-topic, yeah it's better as blog.. yes yes close and reopen as you like, but thanks Stenberg for posting on SO, we close, lock whatever.. but we will not delete your effort in respect

Comment: Admittedly, i'm of the opinion that anything that is closeworthy (other than duplicates) should *eventually* be deleted. This one in particular will never be automatically deleted because members of the community have sent the signal that it is useful/high quality content. Unfortunately... they used the upvote button incorrectly and we're left cleaning up the mess.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601

Comment: is migration really not an option? edit: oh too late anyway, page has been closed

Comment: @ocæon The problem with migration is always where to migrate to -- we really do not want to migrate questions that turn out to be a poor fit to the destination site. The only place in SE I can think of where this question *might* be on-topic is [the Open Source site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com), and even in that case it would be better to ask the folks over there beforehand.

Comment: FWIW, Daniel Stenberg posted his answer in its entirety on his blog. You can see it here: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/04/29/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/

Comment: @KevinB As an open source author (not as an employee or mod), I wanted to address: "It isn't useful information that a developer 2 years from now will look back on..." ...yes, it is. As someone who makes licensing decisions (many of which are specific to software) and having to weigh the same things, this post definitely helps resolve things. I'm not saying it's on or off-topic, I'm just saying: yes, it is useful, and helps in software development. There is value in it.

Comment: please consider [edit]ing to add tag [meta-tag:hot-questions] to help readers see that upvotes on the discussed post weren't acquired organically

Comment: @NickCraver do you believe the value should stay on SO or on the author blog?

Comment: @gnat as much as I want to blame that, in this case the question only got less than 2 hours in the HNQ list. Not sure if that was enough for couple hundred upvotes.

Comment: @Braiam per my reading of timeline it was in HNQ for over 5 hours, not 2. Also timeline shows that all 500+ upvotes on the answer were cast in first 2 days which is totally inorganic. I can assume that some of the votes got to it not directly from sidebar but from social media sharing but that doesn't change much, it is anyway like flash in the pan. [Entertaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773) and not necessarily good quality / useful

Comment: @gnat afaik, closing makes the question inelegible for the list.

Comment: @Braiam no, reopening makes it back to HNQ again, I observed this many times at other sites. Only mod removal guarantees that it won't appear anymore (as a side note I found [this discussion at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327467/165773) about how this question was removed from HNQ)

Comment: It was shared on reddit, then across multiple blogs and other locations relatively quickly. HNQ isn't the only source of increased traffic.

Comment: Locked 3 votes short of great question, oof.

Comment: @alec_a Actually it was above 100 before meta effect kicked in. [He got the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=373215)

Comment: @CodyGray The question is whether it is reasonable to ask a question that would only ever be (directly or indirectly) answerable by essentially one specific individual (or, more generally, a specific well-defined set of individuals, who aren't just "experts"), where no amount of expertise on the subject would lead you to an answer. I would say it isn't reasonable, at which point all that's left is the ability to speculate and share *opinions*.

Comment: Given how few people can answer it, and that the same answer would apply to many other libraries, I'd be inclined to say the question should be generalised to ask about possible incentives for releasing any library for free. However, this might be too broad and would still leave the issue of it not actually being on topic.

Comment: "answers to this question will be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." And yet, the answer to this specific question was entirely backed by reference, facts, and specific expertise. Perhaps this close reason needs to be revisited since it actively prohibits the thing it was supposed to enforce: the production of fact, reference, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have undeleted [What is the incentive for curl to release the library for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884514/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free) The main reason I undeleted it is that the initial author of curl and libcurl answered the question. It seems to me that at the very least, this is an artifact that Stack Overflow can host for [historical purposes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/). Deleting it seems to serve no purpose other than denying the asker a [few hundred points in reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373215/nsivakr?tab=reputation).

I also think the question ought to be unlocked so that both the question and its answer can be voted upon. I obviously have the ability to do this unilaterally as a community manager, but I'd much rather this be something the community decides. (This is another reason to undelete the question, by the way. In the deleted state only a limited number of users can evaluate the content.) One of the reasons Stack Overflow works so very well is that it implements a [token economy](https://jericson.github.io/2019/04/24/crack_overflow.html) that rewards behavior the community approves of. At the time of lock, the question had 123 upvotes to 26 down. The answer had +518/-2. We don't tend to look at this a much as I think we should, but [18 people clicked the upvote arrow while anonymous or not having sufficient reputation to vote](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1040239/anonymous-voting-on-what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-fr). Nobody in that situation clicked the downvote arrow. That indicates that most people who saw the question and nearly everyone who read the answer appreciated the content.

This was overwhelmingly good content by [our simple question grade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) until it was closed. As far as I can tell, the close voters acted because the question is not so much about programming as it is [about software licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384379/1438). But the reason they chose is that it is "primarily opinion-based", which does not seem to be true. Like questions about [why language designers made certain choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609075/why-does-os-path-join-throw-away-arguments), the question can be answered by the person who made the decision or by other evidence they left behind. In this case, *the person who knew definitely* actually answered the question. This is not a matter of opinion, but of historical fact.

We get [an extraordinary volume of bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438) on this site. I don't mean bad in the sense they should be closed, but bad in that they are incomprehensible and unanswerable. It's frustrating for all involved. Closing this question helps that problem not at all. Instead it signals to a portion of the 34,348 people who have viewed the question so far that Stack Overflow does not value interesting content. This is fodder for yet more [articles about how insular Stack Overflow is](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php) without discouraging questions asking for code and other such nuisances even a little.

[Jeff once said](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/):

> Incoming questions are a universal constant, all around us in countless billions. But answers — truly brilliant, amazing, correct answers — are as rare as pearls. Thus, **questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl**. If we have learned anything in the last three years, it is that ***you optimize for pearls, not sand***.

I don't think there is any doubt that the answer under consideration is a pearl. At least I've seen no argument there. If you were given a pearl as a gift, would you throw it out because it was *built on the wrong type of sand*?

Comment: I agree with this viewpoint. Having something by an author of a library that is so popular, that provides insight in some choices is an excellent fit because it is a programming related question, even though it more approaches the philosophy of programming. But me as a programmer I welcome these little pearls, these insights, and they help me to stay motivated and push on and explore new paths. They keep the fun in programming instead of a chore. Because of it's eloquent answer it's turned into a gem, and should be protected as such, as an exception because of the community response.

Comment: There are quite a few mentions of "this answer is not stellar" on this page, which suggests that a lot of people don't agree that it's a pearl. Then again I don't know why there were only two downvotes on the answer.

Comment: I also agree with undeletion. The answer is valuable, even if the question is not. The catch on unlocking it is that we had a tug-of-war in closure and reopening (which would have led to community delete votes out of frustration). If there's a lock that permits voting while discouraging other questions like it and preventing a close/reopen/delete war I'm all for that.

Comment: @AndrasDeak People agree the question is off topic, not that it is a bad answer, I believe. I agree with the use of a "Historical Artifact" lock, as mentioned in another answer but that lock note is not necessarily mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @CodyG. [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/5067311) with 16 upvotes says the answer is meh.

Comment: So, it will be OK to post programmer jokes *if they are good and get many upvotes*?

Comment: @Raedwald: That argument is an example of [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence). This is not a programmer joke.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: 518 people who upvoted the answer on main disagree.

Comment: Well this is a scope game changer. I hope you're here to help mediate more of these.

Comment: @JonEricson With all due respect, what you just did here: '*@AndrasDeak: 518 people who upvoted the answer on main disagree.*' is a false-equivalence. You are equating people voting because they liked the answer with people voting about whether the answer is on-topic/quality. Two very different things.

Comment: I believe equating votes with quality (or topicality) so strongly is a disservice to the site. We all know well that there are many, many cases where those two do not align. IMO is great we have other tools that do not depend on votes directly to moderate and curate the site. Abiding to popularity can easily lead to the wrong results.

Comment: @Yvette what does this change? The question is still off-topic and should be closed, heck, even deleted on its own account. It just has an answer that many don't think deserves to get deleted, for various reasons. Doesn't make the question any more within scope.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the community team thinks it should be on the site, meaning it's good for the site. It's opening a whole new can of worms. So now we need to subjectively work out what's on topic. Heck, anything can be on topic and good for the site now.. Oh not programming jokes, we will have to wait and see what's on topic, as I no longer know.

Comment: Are we setting a precedent to go back and undelete all those ***extremely*** popular questions which collated a massive list of popular books for different languages? If memory serves they had been locked but eventually deleted and they were "more" on-topic than this question.

Comment: @JonEricson speaking of 158 upvotes, how many of these were cast while it was in the hot questions - meaning rather that answer was [entertaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773) and not necessarily good quality / useful? [Revisions history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55884514/revisions) shows it has been hanging in HNQ for quite a while

Comment: This makes me very sad. Question is off topic, and the answer has no technical value whatsoever. Also it was asked two days ago, there is no historical value to be preserved. We are constantly telling people that rules apply equally to all. Now you are saying that they don't. And every effort people put into moderating seems meaningless,,, if you want swamp, you'll eventually have it. I am done fighting the windmills here.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I hear ya. I'm exhausted. I come onto meta, try and do the right thing. It's not always easy, people like to make personal insults when someone with power does something they don't agree with. It's like why am I doing this? It's confusing. The goal posts keep moving. It's ok to make change, but give us a map.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't mind changing rules. But, like you said, first you need to determine what the rules actually are. Also this does not look like changing rules, otherwise post would not be locked - it more seems like one time deal, because this question brought traffic to the site.

Comment: If SE is unwilling to accept community opinion on this question, then...why are there even curator capabilities?  You're telling us that if an owner writes an answer, it is immune to normal curation, and that popularity rules the day over curation.  All you need is to signal boost your package to your users, and bam, immunity for all.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I'm confused but what rules are changed? [Stack Overflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) *no lasting value **whatsoever** should be deleted.* and not even the most upvoted answer on this meta suggest to delete it. Closing is one thing, deleting removing content is another and it always have been.

Comment: The question isn't about curl. It's about free/open software in general, and curl is only mentioned because that's what OP happened to be working with at the time. I think it's reasonable to assume OP did not expect an answer from the curl creator at all and was instead looking for (educated) guesses by other people. That's why I voted to close the question as opinion-based, regardless of the answer.

Comment: @fbueckert: I certainly am willing to accept community opinion on this question. As I said, I could have unlocked and reopened the question, but I have not. If you wish to assert the author of _curl_ is signal boosting his work, that's a novel argument I'd be interested in reading.

Comment: We have decided to bow to the pressure of the masses when it comes to how we curate content.  I find this unacceptable.  If the community team actually likes this kind of signal, then I have **no way** to actually moderate or curate it based on the established precedents we've had for *years*.

Comment: Going forward, what do you really want me to do with questions like this?  I have no idea what to do anymore.  My ability to actually discern topicality and usefulness are thrown out the window.

Comment: I'm asserting that your argument that an author answering a question and getting many upvotes makes their question immune from curation.  You said as much in your first paragraph, and that you'd like to unlock it and reopen it, too, right at the beginning of your second.  Following that argument, you're saying that *any* author that answers a question and gets their users to upvote it makes it valuable.  I think that's a massive loophole, and undermines any trust in allowing users to even close and delete questions in the first place.

Comment: @Makoto just put the close banner on them and focus deletion effort on *no lasting value whatsoever*

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  **That's what I championed in my Meta post.** And now I'm being shown that this is Wrong™.

Comment: @Makoto: I think the signal of voters has _some_ value. It is, in fact, the only way readers regularly communicate with us.

Comment: @JonEricson - I suppose the biggest thing I'm taking umbrage with is that the consensus is that the answer is a "pearl".  On Meta, we're obligated to do a deeper dive into the actual content as opposed to the signal of upvotes (since we know that a mass of people *can* upvote a bad question or bad answer; it just happens in a less public showing).  It feels like we're throwing away the advice and experience of Stack Overflow users for the sake of signal.

Comment: @fbueckert: Neither the question nor the answer is immune from curation _unless they are deleted or locked_.

Comment: @JonEricson - I'm still not sure what we need to do anymore.  My useful metrics and heuristics on how we deal with questions has been invalidated by this response.  How am I supposed to defend or justify curation actions now if it's deemed on high that this question is of lasting value?

Comment: Well...then why did you undelete it?  You're sending a massive signal by overriding the community.

Comment: @fbueckert: I'm overriding the decision of a moderator. I disagree the question should be deleted. I'm _arguing_ it shouldn't be locked or closed either, but those are things I've decided to not take action on.

Comment: @fbueckert Because a moderator deleted it, only another moderator can undelete it

Comment: Well, I think we're stuck.  The community can't delete it because it's not closed *and* it's locked.  I also don't see that actually *happening*, either.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I'm a great advocate of change, so I agree. Change is fine, but on such a ***huge*** site, a small shift at the wheel can change the course of the ship greatly.

Comment: @Makoto: For the moment, you might consider expanding on your argument for why the _answer_ is worthy of deletion.

Comment: @JonEricson your last comment does not make sense. Only a moderator can unlock it. So why aren't you unlocking it? There was as much consensus on locking it as there was on deleting it.

Comment: @JonEricson No, he doesn't need to expand why it's worthy of deletion, the question is clearly off topic.

Comment: @JonEricson:  [Was this reason not sufficient?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354)  I talk about the answer *and* the question in this.  Yikes, it feels like I'm shouting at the wind here...

Comment: @YvetteColomb: It might help to read [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)

Comment: This is one of those no-win scenarios for anyone not a moderator; no one else could have acted on it, and the *overwhelming* consensus in this meta post was that it was off-topic.  Following that, a moderator carrying out that consensus is business as usual, I feel.  Now nobody else can action anything on it, because you've just told us the community is wrong.

Comment: @JonEricson Did you genuinely just link to a post, written by you, in which your accepted answer explicitly points to another answer which says *"consensus is reached when 80-90% of the community agrees on an issue, and one staff member unilaterally decides that all those people are all wrong. Or in more simple terms: Consensus doesn't matter around here."* - Honestly I find that extremely disappointing, and here it certainly appears to be the case.

Comment: @JonEricson The irony of linking a post about consensus that doesn't really have a consensus of votes :D

Comment: Thank you for expressing this opinion Jon Ericson. I'm happy to see that some people think that good content can have a place on this site.

Comment: @Makoto: I re-read your answer. When I read it the first time, I found it extremely dismissal of the author of the answer. Re-reading your answer, I see you did address the content of the answer too. But the overwhelming sense I still get is dismissive. :-(

Comment: @JonEricson dismissive doesn't make the answer wrong though right? Even then, I don't see what is dismissive about the answer either? He just went through it and critically analysed it which shouldn't be conflated with being negative or dismissive.

Comment: @JonEricson so are you going to unlock it? There was no consensus to lock it, just as there's no consensus to delete it. You state in the comments you undeleted it as a mod deleted it and only another mod could undelete it. You do not state that in your answer. If you want a community consensus, then the question needs to be unlocked.

Comment: @PetterFriberg But there is no technical value in this answer. Nothing of practical value. Zero, zilch, none... there is no value to preserve. Every author of every open source library could post something similar.

Comment: Apologies @JonEricson; the neutral tone I took in responding to this question as an artifact on what we should do when this happens again was not meant to be "dismissive".

Comment: @fbueckert "_Following that, a moderator carrying out that consensus is business as usual_". What was that? The original deletion? I didn't see any consensus here deciding to delete the answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak going off what Jon suggested earlier, the up-votes to down-votes ratio in *this* question when compared with what is being suggested (locking or deleting as opposed to leaving it open).

Comment: I suppose I have a new insight into how my posts are interpreted, though. I'll try to not come across as dismissive in the future, if I can.

Comment: @Makoto you weren't dismissive, it was a good answer. Thorough and I didn't repeat much when I made my answer, as you'd said it all.

Comment: Just curious -- You make the point that no anonymous users downvoted the answer. How many anonymous users downvote at all? I'm thinking it's a very small percentage of the overall number of votes made by anonymous users, and that the anonymous upvote/downvote ratio on the libCurl question is close to the overall ratio.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I was subtly referring to the implicit bias in interpreting my answer (i.e. first read). I can't fix that; all I can do is make my communications clearer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the thing that Jon isn't considering is that anonymous users tend not to get to recently asked questions due, well, being recent and not being indexed. 95% of all traffic to SO is search engine driven, after all.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: As a rule, anonymous readers are [far more critical of posts than regular voters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1040283/how-many-anonymous-upvotes-and-downvotes-are-there?opt.textResults=true).

Comment: @Braiam what if someone on Crocheted Oven Mitts Stack Exchange finds the post in HNQ? Then they probably won't have an account on SO.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks, that's interesting.

Comment: @AndrasDeak for less than two hours? Sure. (BTW, I love (!) that now we have a timestamp for being in the HNQ)

Comment: @Braiam From my understanding, this Q & A pair got mentioned on an external site, like Reddit or whatever. That will bring in a lot of anonymous users. In this case, primed to upvote due to the selfless nature of the answer. In any case, my comment was meant to figure out whether the fact that no one downvoted was abnormal or not. Jon showed that it is unusual, so I consider the comment's curiosity satisfied.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar sure no technical value but our mission is *collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world*. Personally I think you are overestimating the "danger" of keeping an off-topic question not deleted, if the community like it (with the only measure that we have) and meta have put a nice close banner on it (stating it's not on-topic), why are not everybody happy? Maybe you should see it as great sign post for what is off-topic and let the community users that like it continue to read and reference it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Well, it's a sign post that questions like it are off-topic, but in the meantime, go ahead and ask them -- you'll gather a ton of rep before they get locked.

Comment: @HereticMonkey well if the answer *collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world* which is not every day so be it, however I mostly see "Plz debug this, tanks in advantage".

Comment: @HereticMonkey the Q&A could be made community wiki to remove rep from the picture...

Comment: @PetterFriberg The answer not increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge. It is merely reflecting the reasoning behind the lack of remuneration for a single library by the author. Something the author has also detailed in a blog post, so the answer on Stack Overflow is actually a duplicate of that purported knowledge. The fact that most questions coming into SO are crap is, again, a separate problem from this specific question getting deleted or not.

Comment: @JonEricson regarding your comment on anonymous readers being far more critical, I would guess that's partly probably because they don't lose rep. I would have downvoted a lot more answers over the years if I didn't lose rep for each one. At least for me, retaining the ability to perform a certain set of curation abilities on a daily basis is too valuable to drop 50 rep per day, because I'm not one of the 100 users who answers so frequently (or a circa 2008 user w/ 100k rep over time) who can afford to do so. At least now at 10k+ I can safely downvote more frequently, but not by a huge margin.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The damage has already been done. Someone asked and someone answered an off topic question and both received an enormous amount of reputation. It's already locked, and locked questions don't accumulate votes. I'm fine with that, although I still think it should be deleted since keeping it increases the risk of more questions like it.

Comment: Now, the content is on the author blog. Should SO maintain a resource if it's available in a better form elsewhere?

Comment: @Braiam Removing questions/answers "if it's available in a better form elsewhere" could torpedo a lot of content.  SO has many answers that are better explained by blog posts or websites.  We even link to those sources in our answers, and we often include relevant snippets of the source in the answer in case that source disappears in the future.

Comment: @Rakuen42 When is it that _"SO has many answers that are better explained by blog posts or websites"_? SO is _undisputed the best_ at providing technical answers on programming.

Comment: @PasserBy I look at SO (and SE in general) as a knowledge index that has the veneer of a Q&A site.  It's a one-stop shop for material on a focused subject area.  It is the best at providing technical answers, but that does not mean it is the original source of all those answers.  I point that out in the remainder of the comment you're replying to.

Comment: @Rakuen42 _"that does not mean it is the original source of all those answers"_ this isn't factually based, but either way SO either does a good job at hosting an answer or not. If it doesn't, we nuke it. And no, this preserves most of the content on SO.

Comment: @PasserBy I would agree that SO does a good job at curating content.  That's why we're all here! :)  That said, are you saying you have never seen a single answer on this site that is a link to an off-site resource and a snippet of that material?

Comment: Real pearl and imitation pearl isn't easy to distinguish. With all due respect, I fail to see any value in historical locks to this post, in comparison which is applied to various posts previously. In many previous posts, they still bring value to us as a programmer. But this post doesn't seem to add anything of value.

Comment: Why am I being censored? I posted a legitimate concern in this comment chain earlier, and it has since been removed.

Comment: Eliminating the "water cooler" type questions was once a core focus of this site. Now with the undeletion of this question and Shog reopening the "what languages were around 50 years ago" question, it seems that's another rule which will be overridden by staff if the content is popular. Yet another data point for the 2019 edition of the "why SO is going down the drain" data set...

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, I would have downvoted it but - as I only use SO extremely sparingly anymore - I just saw it and its locked....so no options at all

Comment: @JGreenwell I see you've read the most glorious special SO newsletter ;) Oh, or maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385542/stack-overflow-is-undermining-community-standards-by-promoting-an-off-topic-ques I guess

Comment: @AndrasDeak lol, no it was the newsletter - I still point my students to the canonical Python questions so its in my "just in case something relevant to building a lecture or adding as a resource in a course comes up" large set of newletters, feeds, & free journals ... building next fall's courses when I caught this

Comment: I haven't followed the discussion of this *particular* Q/A in detail (because it was just too much, and ... frankly: some decisions made by stackoverflow moderators/employees are beyond what a sensible person can comprehend). But just in case it was not mentioned yet: Try to imagine that the question was not about curl in particular, and imagine that "someone (who wrote a certain library)" answered it. The Q/A would have been downvoted into oblivion in this case. The fact that the *question* was narrow and the *answer* was narrow could even be seen as a counterargument for keeping it...

Comment: It gets worse: whoever closed the question should be ashamed - they claimed that the question is opinion-based. Like, lookie here, the question is the absolute *opposite* of opinion-based. It demands (to be any good) the answer by the curl's author, and the author gave such an answer. **The only bloody way the question could be ever opinion-based would be if somehow the author of curl was forbidden by the SO rules to answer it**. In the absence of such a bar, the question is completely objective. It's not like anyone's opinion drives curl's authors. Whatever they state is fact!

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: Honestly it doesn't require the author of curl to answer on Stack Overflow. If they have ever answered the question (on their blog, in an interview, in the code, on a mailing list or wherever) someone could have quoted them in an answer. But at this point, closing this sort of question [signals a commitment to quality](https://jlericson.com/2019/05/20/meristocracy.html) even with precisely the opposite effect.

Comment: @JonEricson  I *hinted* that perhaps, just perhaps, such questions could be flagged (say: mod-edited) with an admonition that the only unopinionated answers can, by definition almost, come from the people being asked about, or by summarizing direct first-hand accounts originating with those people (e.g. if someone asked about Linux, it'd be OK only to report on LKML posts by Linus and other core contributors). Commitment to quality, as you define it, belongs in a fast food chain Franchise Operator's Manual, replacing thought with procedure. Maybe you want SO to be McDonalds. I don't. Think!

Comment: @JonEricson IOW, there's clearly no "one fits all" way to define what's opinion based and what's not, but as long as one can clearly outline what would constitute a reasonable non-opinion-based answer, then that's sufficient bar for entry I think - a bar miles higher than the vast majority of the questions from first- and second-time askers. I find lots of the value on this site from decent questions that got retroactively closed - they are like living paleo-organisms, like the placentas we got gifted from some patogen eons ago.

Comment: @JonEricson Finally, I'm beginning to question the wiseness of opinion-basedness as a valid sole rejection criterion. Our culture, including software development culture, and all of its artifacts, is extremely arbitrary, and it's very much highly opinionated people that had the drive and punch-through to start what's now commonplace - be it programming languages, communications protocols, etc. I'd take some opinionated wisdom over mindless objectivity at any time, day or night.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: I think we are in violent agreement. ;-) It's certainly been my experience that "objectively correct answers" are often the result of hard won experience. Trouble is, my experience might not be yours. In any case, there is an answer here, SO got it right from the expert's keyboard and decided it wasn't good enough.

Comment: SO has a problem with emergent behavior among its users that agrees with the letter of the "law" but is totally indecent and just nonsense, really. Worse yet - I'm not immune to that either and I'm sure I must have slipped here and there. The lecture of the Hitchhiker's Guide was of help (seriously - it gives perspective!). Their bureaucratic approach induces behaviors that do mostly the right thing, but where they fail - they fail so spectacularly that an Ipecac contamination of an urban water supply would be comparatively minor. Stuff makes you want to throw up...

Answer (score 91):

Allow me to suggest an alternate interpretation of this question. We already allow questions that inquire on the motivations for language features. So extending that to library features is hardly unreasonable.

*However*, that's not really what this question is asking, is it? It's asking about the motivation for a library's license. That is essentially asking about a *delivery mechanism* for the library.

I submit that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, on the grounds that it is not really about *programming*. It's about the reasoning behind the license for a product. And while such questions can be highly useful to programmers, that doesn't make them appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: curl is open source, so if we're going to approach it as a licensing question then the Open Source exchange might be another candidate as it explicitly allows licensing questions.

Comment: Minor nit:  "for free" does not always presume "licensed".  It could be the case that the software is released devoid of any license, so I'm not sure I agree with the angle of this being a licensing question.

Comment: I bet it's off-topic on every SE site as on SO, I can't really see how you solve the problem, just leave it closed on SO and let those who enjoy the answer, enjoy

Comment: @Makoto Could be, but in this case it isn't. The license for curl is at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html. It says the license is "inspired by MIT/X, but not identical."

Comment: @Makoto If software is released without license, it isn't free and you aren't able to use it (or at least, it would be a legal minefield, because without a license, you don't have the right to use the work produced by someone else). Even just saying "feel free to use it" is a license...

Comment: So, it is a question about software licensing, which is [off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing).

Comment: Software Engineering no longer handles licensing questions.  These should be directed to either Law or Open Source.

Comment: Since when do we allow questions asking about motivations for language features? Those are equally opinion based.

Comment: @jpmc26: Since... always? Some of them get closed when they're too opinionated, but we allow quite a few of them when they're reasonably focused and potentially answerable. We get questions like these with some regularity in the C++ tag.

Answer (score 64):

The question is off topic.

The answer is now available on [the author's blog](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/04/29/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/).

It's great to have the creator of the project on the site, but it's still not the place to tell everyone about it. A blog is better with a link in the profile. It puts a message there that it's ok to post these types of questions. Does this mean we can ask questions about every library, programming resource and it's creation?

Upvotes don't justify keeping it on the site.

I've deleted the post.

*The post has since been undeleted and the undeletion is [addressed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384400/3956566). I still think it's off topic for the site and defending it to stay on the site is confusing.*

Comment: Not to open another can of worms but when should we lock as opposed to outright delete? From what I could pickup, historical locks are used on content which fit a certain criteria (off-topic, popular, and close/reopen loop) so my question is, why not just delete all historical posts? Where do we draw the line?

Comment: @Script47 the lock was designed in a way meant for "useful information that isn't available elsewhere and we would not like to lose" (paraphrasing Tim Post). Once information is available elsewhere (or the content is so obsolete that the usefulness is suspect), it can be deleted. [Like this example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280829/792066)

Comment: @Braiam It can also be considered not useful for reasons other than being obsolete.  Makoto's answer breaks down in more detail why the information in the answer just isn't all that useful

Comment: @Servy I think that was covered in "useful information that isn't available elsewhere". I deliberately made obsolescent a subset of usefulness.

Comment: @Script47 let's face it, the answer had little value in terms of programming.

Comment: @Servy yep I didn't go into repetitive detail, just wanted to post that I'd deleted it so objections could be raised here.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm not saying it has, I'm asking regarding generics, forget this question / answer, what should we do about the rest and more importantly, going ahead how should we handle them?

Comment: @Script47 we tend to handle them either by flagging and moderator discretion or people literally post on meta about specific posts.

Comment: Sad.  I looked forward to reaading the post.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: "*I've deleted the post.*" Wait, what? The whole point of this topic was to bring a matter of contention to the awareness of the community so that they could make a decision on the matter. One would ordinarily think that this would require more than, I don't know, *five hours* of discussion to be reached. You're a community moderator: that means you enforce the rules as the community dictates. If the community is divided (as seems clear in this case), then you're supposed to *wait* until we've reached a decision.

Comment: Years ago, we had a huge, week-long argument about when to delete what that eventually led to the "Historical Lock" policy. The moderators didn't just decide to cut off the discussion; they allowed the debate to actually happen and play out for some time. And while this is in fact just one question, one might think it's worth letting things lie in lockdown for a bit longer than 5 hours before making a decision for us. I don't feel that this deciding for the community when the community is somewhat ambivalent about an issue is appropriate for elected moderators.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  To play Devil's Advocate - what is really left to discuss?  No one was disagreeing with the fact that the question was off-topic.  The last thing to really decide was if the question fit within the criteria for preservation for a historical post.  There's *not* a lot of posts which suggest it's worth it or teaches anyone much of anything, so...why belabor the point?

Comment: @historystamp If you want to read the Daniel's answer [you can read it here on his blog](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/04/29/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you... at least one of the mods had the guts to do the right thing. Not saying that taking time to think is necessarily bad, but in cases like this any reluctance to act fast according to established rules sends confusing signals to the community.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thank you! Honestly it was so off topic for the site, I don't understand why people want to hang onto it. The OP can add a link to the blog in their SO profile.  I've copped heat over it. It's like sometimes the site loses perspective over some things.

Comment: It would be great if you contacted the author of the blog post so they can remove the part that says it was deleted for "unspecified" reasons...you specified the reason here.

Comment: @gparyani I've left a comment for the author under the post directing them to this question.

Comment: There is also a section for blog post comments as well as an email address for the author, if you want.

Comment: @YvetteColomb doing the right thing again. Thank $diety for her as a moderator!

Comment: @IanKemp thanks! It's people like you who keep me going! :) Nice to see you.

Comment: I guess consensus only rules when it is in the direction convenient to SE.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but want to suggest that maybe next time the timing could be a bit more relaxed.

Comment: @Trilarion if it wasn't as shift as this was, the author won't probably notice the deletion and move it to their blog. The only reason why was it moved to the blog was precisely because it was deleted. Then the strongest argument for deletion (it's elsewhere in a better form) wouldn't have happened.

Comment: @NicolBolas since when mods enforce "as community dictates"? They enforce as rules dictate - nothing more, nothing less. And they're specifically SUPPOSED do break bad behavior of community as well.

Answer (score 36):

Well this looks like a curious case.  Admittedly, lightning doesn't strike very often - that is to say, either a lead developer or architect on a language or library doesn't normally post answers - but it happens, from time to time.

**That shouldn't overshadow what duty we have here.**  Irrespective of whether or not the original maintainer/author/architect responded to a question, we still have to ask ourselves if the question is worth keeping around in the first place.

Let's look at the actual question being posed.

> I've been wondering: what is the incentive for the curl creators to release the entire library for free?
>
> Is it purely to help their fellow developers?

At ***best***, the *question* is largely subjective.  The motives of someone developing a piece of software for others to use is not our concern, and should not be within any technical scope we employ here.

Let's [take a look at the answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885729/1079354) - specifically, does it actually answer the question?

...*Kinda*.

> Now, why do I and my fellow curl developers still continue to develop
>   curl and give it away for free to the world?
>
> [...]
>
> 2. I think it's still the right thing to do. I'm proud of what we've accomplished and I truly want to make the world a better place and I
>      think curl does its little part in this.

The rest of that answer is really *just* conversational.  They're admittedly gushing with pride over what they've done (and they have absolutely every right to be since I can't imagine a world *without* `curl`), but the signal-to-noise ratio is pretty low here.

We have standards for [historical locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/175248).  The criteria for locking are as follows:

> 1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic question, **and**
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, **and**
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, **and**
> 4. The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once.

I would strongly, strongly argue that the post is *not* stellar, so it shouldn't be historically locked.

Specifically, the minimal guidance of the 3rd rule in "We Hate Fun Here" would be:

> Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

Thinking that something is the right thing to do isn't *exactly* what I'd call making someone better at their job.  It isn't the case that the post imparts any explicit or tacit wisdom at creating open source projects, nor does it truly articulate or describe the perils of getting into open-source projects (the fact that one's time is not free is not exclusive to open-source projects and isn't a hidden fact elsewhere).

I'm glad to see that the original creator did respond but I can't justify keeping the question around, personally.

Comment: So just delete it? and continue to fill SO with "Can you peeps debug this?"

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  That's cool; you don't *have* to answer debugging questions.  But at some point we're going to have to stop and ask ourselves what kinds of questions we're *really* trying to answer.  If questions like *this* suit your fancy instead, you should propose a new exchange site for them.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: "*So just delete it? and continue to fill SO with "Can you peeps debug this?"*" I don't know what the one has to do with the other. You seem to be trying to conflate two entirely distinct issues. Do you think this question not being closed will in any way affect the quantity of "Can you peeps debug this?" questions?

Comment: **Do note** I never stated it should not be closed, I just can't understand your frenzy to delete it, you are starting at the wrong place cc @NicolBolas

Comment: We already have standards and guidelines for 99% of the stuff we see on the exchanges already.  We should be prepared to apply the same standards we've been championing as hallmarks of good questions into *every* question that comes our way.  It's the case that exceptions happen; I'm merely arguing that this *isn't* one of those cases.

Comment: I don't *altogether* disagree. My feelings on this are quite mixed, which is why I didn't take unilateral mod action last night when it first came to my attention. The only thing I feel strongly about is that it is *not* "POB". I do agree that it is off-topic, but more for the reasons Nicol Bolas presents in his answer. I have also been very hesitant to delete it (or allow it to be deleted), because I view that as throwing away value. But...you (and others) make a good point that, despite the votes, the answer isn't actually all that useful or enlightening, so I'm starting to reconsider.

Comment: @Makoto sorry for my first comment but it just seems useless to delete it, what is the actual purpose of this considering all the other **** we keep.

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  I can at least appreciate your frustration, but that doesn't change the fact that we're objectively looking at *this* specific question and trying to justify if it's something we should keep around on the site.  Beyond that, you're likely going to have to take your frustration on the kinds/quality of questions we get here to a different Meta post.

Comment: Just close and lock it (no need even for historical lock) then we carry on to next

Comment: If only it were that easy @PetterFriberg...we now have a situation where a question has very high signal (e.g. votes/views) and is of low quality.  Our automated tooling to remove questions which are of low quality won't apply here since this question and its answers make those tools entirely moot.  This is definitely something exceptional that needs to be dealt with.  It'll never be deleted automatically, and locking it now just to delete it years down the road would only be worse.  If it's not worth keeping, it's not immune from deletion.

Comment: It is worth keeping, people enjoy the insights, it may inspire more to develop open-source, it may encourage lead developer of curl to answer "on-topic" questions, no need to ever delete we need to focus on much bigger problems

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  Not sure if you noticed, but [Daniel Stenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg) has 33K+ reputation.  He's well-incentivized to answer on-topic questions (and has been doing so fairly consistently).  The rest of your points aren't as concrete; developing "open-source" software isn't the same as maintaining or actually living in the "open-source" frame-of-mind. Lastly, all of the "bigger" problems are problems that would require [developer time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), and we can't get our calendars to sync up.

Comment: I did notice and that's a stronger reason to keep it, I will defend any off-topic answer also from you. Let the deletion be in 6-8 also :)

Comment: I agree with this answer. That answer is a blog post. Stack Overflow is not a blog.

Comment: It's not a subjective question, because it can have a definitive answer: documentation provided by the developers about their actual motivations. A subjective question is one in which there can never be a definitive answer, like "which is the best language" or "are gotos a good idea".

Comment: I must confess @SteveBennett, I am in **no mood** to participate in the vocabulary triathlon.  Everyone's motivations for writing and/or releasing software for free are different, which by definition implies there is no definite answer.  If such documentation existed *before* the question was posted, it wouldn't have prompted the question in the first place.

Comment: Everyone's motivations might be different, but the question specifically asked about the motivations of a very small group of people. A question for which the answer is not knowable is not the same as a subjective question.

Answer (score 23):

> Should we allow this type of Q&A on Stack Overflow?

As a rule? No.

As an exception? Sure.

The questioner specifically asks:

> what is the incentive for the curl creators to release the entire library for free?

which is enquiring regarding the motives of *why* the developers released it for free and that is the definition of primarily opinion-based and I'm sure normally it would've been down-voted to oblivion.

> Should we just historical lock the question for posterity?

Absolutely, that's what it was created for as per [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for):

> A historical lock is a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as historical artifacts. Questions which are historically locked feature the following post notice:
>
> A historical lock preserves content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on. Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once, or subject to a close or delete war.

and it also meets the criteria provided:

1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic question, **and** (opinion based/too broad)
2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, **and** (it gives insights into a popular library from a unique perspective)
3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, **and** (33,609 times, and 500+ up-votes on the answer)
4. The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once. (self-explanatory)

(parenthesis explanation mine)

The appropriate action was taken by closing and locking.

Comment: "was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope"...   Doesn't this line imply that the item in question has been around for a lot longer than one day?

Comment: @DonBoitnott who cares, if the lock serve our purpose: keep the effort of Stenberg on SO for others to read, without having endless close reopen battle so be it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That would be anyone who is interested in seeing the devices available on SO used properly, and not just however it serves your purpose.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Do you have some reference for why it's "improper" to use a historical lock on a new post?  What about it's description or guidelines indicates the post can't be new?

Comment: @Servy: Maybe there's the fact that the *very first word* in the thing is "Historical". Stack Overflow, and an oddly large number of its users, has a big problem with using words to mean things other than their obvious meaning. I suppose [on a network where "off topic" is used for things that have nothing to do with topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086/164572), using a "Historical Lock" on a question that was asked less than 24-hours ago makes sense. It always seems like Opposite Day on SO when it comes to naming things...

Comment: @NicolBolas Something can be both historic and recent.  Historic doesn't mean "old".  In fact it's quite common for historic events to be recognized as historic events *immediately after they happen*, even though there are certainly times where an event's historic significance isn't recognized for quite some time.

Comment: @Servy: That is the exact same kind of logic that leads to us using "off topic" for things that have nothing to do with topicality. The fact that a person could come up with an interpretation of the word "historical" (not "historic", FYI) where it *could* apply does not mean that it represents a good use of the word. If you have to think about why a word would be appropriate, if you have to come up with a complex rationalization for it, then it's *the wrong word*. That's basic writing 101: you use the word that gives *exactly* the impression you want.

Comment: @NicolBolas So because you don't understand what the word actually means we shouldn't use it to mean what the word *actually means*?  If you want to change the name of historical locks to something you think is better, by all means, propose that change, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be used for things it applies to on the grounds that the misunderstood meaning of the name doesn't apply to the situation even though the actual meaning and description apply.

Comment: @Servy: Is it not true that the Historical Lock was created specifically to handle questions which were asked at a time that they were considered appropriate? Is it not true that the term "Historical Lock" was *specifically chosen* because it gives the reader the idea that such questions are a matter of "history" (ie: the past) and thus not acceptable in the present? Now, you're trying to revise the meaning of the concept, appropriating the name as completely literal, and thus, any question is equally worthy of "historical" since it was by definition asked in the past.

Comment: @Servy: If your view of "historical" is such that any question applies, then why put the word there at all? It's utterly insane to think that the term is meant to apply equally well to a question asked 24 hours ago as one asked 8 years ago. The word "history" has the definition of "past", but it's not a synonym for "past". We have two words for the concept because they have different connotations. Ignoring those connotations represents bad communication.

Comment: The *vast* majority of historically locked questions were not appropriate when they were asked.  It's useful *when* a question becomes off topic when it was previously on topic, that's *one* of it's use cases, but it's not *exclusively* for that situation.  I'm not revising the meaning of it; it has always been applicable to questions that were close worthy when first asked, even when it was created.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not a big fan of the the term either, although I don't have any particularly good alternatives.  If you come up with an alternative that you think is clearer and wouldn't give the false impression that it can only apply to very old posts, then by all means, propose it.  I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Stack Exchange defined historical as something to do with significance: "I'd question how that question even qualifies as historically significant. Only 15 votes? Only 720 views? Pfft. Throw that in the trash can where it belongs. It's not even a question, it failed, and barely anyone ever even looks at it." [animuson's comment at this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8566/169736) [But he now equates it to age?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253057/have-a-special-lock-for-meta-sites-for-historical-out-of-date-policy-decisions#comment826420_253057) So :shurg: cc Nicol @Servy

Comment: @Servy To answer your specific question to me, I'd say that I tend to consider the word "historic" to align with a thing that has history.  Perhaps it's not a literal meaning, but I bet more people than not would agree.  Also, there's this:  `was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic`.  To me, that implies that time has passed...the post had a certain fame, then somehow the perception of it changed.  That really can't happen in 24 hours.  Just my opinion, I guess.

Comment: @DonBoitnott The only thing I would point out is that the definition of '*historic*' according to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+historic) is: '*famous or important in history, **or potentially so**.*' - This question and answer had (has?) the *potential* to become historically popular / valuable. I guess you need to get the meaning contextually. For example, when scientist or any other person accomplishes something groundbreaking they say '*a historic breakthrough has been made...*' which goes back to the *potential* of being historic.

Comment: I'd hardly argue the content was stellar, it might be a interesting read if you are personally invested in curl, but it's otherwise just a page from someone's diary. That said, locks have been put on [worse posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3A1+closed%3A1) before, I agree locking was appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

There's a problem with equating votes with quality. Remember, voting reasons are, by design, between you and whatever you believe or not believe in. I presume most of the votes are more or less the same as these comments, [from the blog post](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/04/29/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/):

> [image: comments from the author blog post]

That's why it's very dangerous using votes as anything like quality. They may reflect quality at some point, but in this case it doesn't nor does reflect topically.

Comment: The same could be said about random water cooler questions and jokes and other *lower common denominator* content.

Comment: This illustrates the main problem of POB questions on SO: voting can easily turn into a statement in {dis-)agreement. Same with the question itself: it does not strike me as very well researched/useful, and might just as well have received most of those upvotes because there is a great answer on it, not because the question itself was of such splendid quality.

Comment: @Adriaan: If that answer hadn't been posted, the question would have been downvoted to oblivion, closed and deleted in short order. I know this because I've seen this type of question before.

Comment: Votes are pretty much our only signal of quality. (Assuming you include downvotes and close votes, that is.) I'm open to the idea that _these_ votes aren't useful, but it seems a bit of a stretch to assume commenters on a blog post on some other site are good evidence. (Now comments on the post itself are good evidence and do seem similar to these. They've been deleted, however.) Is this a rabbit trail we want to follow or only when the votes are contrary to our own opinion?

Comment: @JonEricson I ignore anything but the post itself when evaluating it. I'm evaluating the post, not the irrelevant content surrounding it. That's the only way were a critical and unbiased assessment of a post can be done. The only post where I take in a specific piece of context, is when the post is an answer and to evaluate it I have to see the question. My note here is that trying to equate votes to quality isn't entirely true due the nature of voting.

Comment: @Braiam so also meta is rather useless, we just nominate a dictator and they decided what is right and wrong

Comment: @PetterFriberg that's a straw man argument. Main is dedicate to be objective, meta is subjective. So, evaluation of subjective posts are done by how convincing is the argument presented.

Comment: So votes on meta is a sign of quality and votes on main are not, hmm so meta are different users, trying to represent the community but fundamentally does not trust the community because they know they know better.

Comment: Braiam no voting system is perfect but still I think prefeer democracy which includes all, I prefeer not to elect you as an elite that decides for me

Comment: @PetterFriberg "So votes on meta is a sign of quality and votes on main are not" are you deliberately misrepresenting my words? I said **votes don't equate quality**. That's the only reference to votes I said.

Comment: Yeah maybe I don't understand, but what I'm trying to say, is if that's true (which surely is partial true in any voting system), it is valid also for meta. As a consequence we have no system to determine what is right and wrong only a bunch of non rated different ideas, so now what?

Comment: *How convincing is the argument presented*? Who decided if it is of *quality*?

Comment: @Adriaan Votes are *always* a statement of agreement or disagreement. If you vote up a post, you are agreeing with the author that it's useful/helpful/correct. If you vote down a post, you are disagreeing with the author on that. The argument that people voting up an answer "because they agree with it" being a deceptive or harmful signal does not seem to have any merit based on the arguments presented here so far.

Answer (score 16):

Yesterday, taking a cue from remarks about migration amidst this discussion, I have asked at the Open Source Meta whether the question would be a good fit for that site. The initial reaction has been broadly positive.

(A note before the link to the Open Source Meta Q&A: please **do not vote on anything there** unless you are a regular on that site, as we might easily drown the signal from the smaller community over there. With that covered, here is the link: https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/826/14879)

If the Open Source SE community is willing to take the question, I believe migrating it is a no-brainer, as the best resolution we can have for this situation. On the one hand, Daniel Stenberg's answer would be kept within the Network (with even a handy redirect from Stack Overflow to prevent link rot); on the other hand, we would, as far as this concrete case is concerned, get a reprieve from facing head on the various tricky questions raised throughout this discussion.

Comment: Do note there is now an answer to the Open Source Meta question that, unlike the first one there, argues against migration.

Answer (score -7):

Jon Ericson♦ to [the rescue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384400/5292302), thanks! This answer was not written correctly to gain the support and understanding what needed to be done.

---

Dear [Daniel Stenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg)

## You made curl!

Thank you for your answer on Stack Overflow, it is inspiring and interesting to read about your effort developing such an important open-source library.

We are grateful for your effort not only developing the library, but also sharing your knowledge and thoughts on Stack Overflow.

<sup>PS:
The question was unfortunately off-topic, so we had to close it and to avoid close-reopen battle also lock it, but I don't believe we should delete it.</sup>

---

[From Stack Overflow help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) emphasis mine.

> **When should I delete questions?**

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value **whatsoever** should be flagged and deleted.

I consider Daniel Stenberg's answer to have lasting value and therefore it should not be deleted. The answer can remain on Stack Overflow with the current close banner (or off-topic not about programming) which will clearly indicated that it's not a good fit in general for Stack Overflow. The risk that it will be *used as justification* is unfounded, instead it stands as example both of interesting answer and off-topic question. If the close-reopen battle continues moderator can lock the post.

Comment: "We will not delete it" is a ***strong*** statement.  If nothing else, that's quite literally what we're deciding in this Meta question.

Comment: Exactly, so that's my answer and the motivation is above.

Comment: Sorry, but guy with the 30K something reputation should know better than answering off topic posts. If he could restrain himself from answering we would not have to deal with this mess in the first place. Just nuke the whole thing. This answer belongs to a blog, not here. We either have rules or we don't.