# How should we address the "I assigned you this homework" answer shared on /r/ProgrammerHumor?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645305/1709587) is a bad answer of which half the content is irrelevant. The question asks how to insert a string in the middle of another string (and notes that the asker wants to do this numerous times). The answer reads:

> You don't need to loop it because the loop is already handled in main. So you just need to use String's substring function to reconstruct a String made of the first half of one, then the second, then the other half of the first.
>
> How do I know the loop is already in main? Because I assigned you this homework.

The only relevant content here is:

> use String's substring function to reconstruct a String made of the first half of one, then the second, then the other half of the first.

... which is already covered better in [corsiKa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442989/1709587) from a year earlier, which actually shows code that does this. However, the new, duplicate answer has received lots of upvotes due to being shared on /r/ProgrammerHumor, and has been accepted by the asker, perhaps because he found it funny.

What should we do with this?

Letting it stand unedited seems wrong. Half the content is irrelevant and confusing to anyone arriving on the page sincerely seeking an answer (since it starts off by talking about some loop in main that is definitely not present anywhere in the question). In normal circumstances, it'd be right to edit such content out.

But editing it out *also* seems wrong, since that conflicts with the intent of the answerer. This answer was never meant to actually help people arriving at the question looking for a solution, which corsiKa had already provided; rather, its purpose is to mock the asker for cheating on their homework. If we remove the mockery of the asker, then we remove the entire point of the answer - and the thing that it gained 200 upvotes for.

That leaves me thinking that the only unproblematic approach is to delete the answer. But when I flagged for deletion...

> The only actually-relevant detail in this answer, for any new reader arriving here, is the suggestion to use `substring`, which is already covered in more detail in corsiKa's answer. It adds no value to the page and has been upvoted heavily purely due to irrelevant content (specifically, that the answerer recognises this as a homework task they set) and due to this post being linked from /r/ProgrammerHumor. Can we just delete it?

... I got declined:

> In short, you're asking for the deletion of a post just because it got more upvotes than it should have received. Seems a wrong reason to delete a post, isn't it?

So, what should we do? It still seems to me that deletion here is warranted and I don't like just leaving it alone since it's a prominent broken window and a nuisance to that question's tens of thousands of viewers (or at least the subset of them who are sincerely seeking an answer).

Comment: Meh, this seems like much ado about nothing. The answer would have been forgotten in the sands of time, if not for that reddit post.  The views are all from reddit, and therefore it doesn't seem to cause much trouble. We can prolly just lock it and leave it, just like the parsing html answer, if you are concerned about it getting a lot of upvotes.

Comment: @BhargavRao Locking doesn't really achieve anything besides making it impossible to ever edit out the confusing/irrelevant content. Not sure that's a positive thing.

Comment: "we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..." (Jeff Atwood, [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: ...by the way, if there is indeed much earlier and better answer, these matters were discussed in [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601)

Comment: Why is the sharing in /r/ProgrammerHumor relevant? And if it is, shouldn't we find silly posts on reddit and ridicule those posts here on Meta. Oh wait, we can't, that is not on topic here ...

Comment: @rene It wouldn't be the same anyway, we'd be making fun of joke posts while the Reddit users are willingly doing fraudulent voting in serious posts to mess with the site.

Comment: I believe the answer should be deleted to foster a healthy community. If a joke is all there is to get me 200 upvotes, up to 2015 reps, and a gold "Great Answer" badge, what is the point of another user putting his/her real effort providing good content in SO anymore?

Comment: I think the answer should be left as-is as a cautionary tale so that students can see that their teachers also use Stack Overflow. This will contribute towards a healthy SO community.

Comment: @YongQuan I know of two questions that should be closed and deleted, but instead ended up being discussed on meta, with a historical lock on it. One of those is [the cURL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384376/6296561), which an SE employee undeleted after a mod deleted it. Later, SE [promoted the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385542/6296561). We're past "fostering a healthy community", and more over on (failing to) repair the several quality problems that've been discussed repeatedly. The meta effect (or reddit effect in this case) will never change. Visibility => votes

Comment: I was wondering why a seemingly low-lying post was suddenly getting a bunch of votes. I thought maybe it was people early in summer school taking intro programming courses. Should have known it was Reddit. For the record, I fully support whatever consensus the community/moderators/staff reach. (Look at me assuming we ever reach consensus about anything, how cute.)

Comment: For reference the nonsense [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/cauwnu/when_you_get_help_on_stackoverflow_from_the/). The [answers timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24645305/timeline).

Comment: How about editing it in shape to be on-topic & helpful, then adding a *if you are here for a good laugh or if this is homework, see revision history* ?

Comment: @JonasWilms because that notice would still be "noise". The answer should be deleted, not much else to it.

Comment: I'd be happy with a lock. It is probably delete-worthy, but the reputation of the Stack Overflow community on Reddit is very mixed, and there's not much value in kicking that hornet's nest because we can. It is just one post `:-)`.

Comment: The question itself is now closed. Perhaps some users find that the question itself doesn't belong on SO and will use their moderation powers to that extent in the future...

Comment: Did you already notice the moderator note ;)

Comment: @halfer '*It is probably delete-worthy, but the reputation of the Stack Overflow community on Reddit is very mixed, and there's not much value in kicking that hornet's nest because we can.*' - We're not doing it because we can or to spite Reddit users, we're doing it because it's standard procedure. I don't see why we're trying to placate a group of people by changing how the community has worked. '*It is just one post*' - That's where it starts. As for the reputation part, that is a dying meme. People take use of SO each day without problem.

Comment: @Script47: I don't buy the "slippery slope" argument. The number of off-topic but amusing posts that have been locked in probably some 0.01% of the questions asked. If we get hundreds of these, then sure, we can handle the flood differently.

Comment: @halfer feel free to discard the slippery slope argument, but the other still stands, if we delete it, we'd be doing nothing out of the ordinary. If you are saying the only reason we should keep it is to keep a few Reddit users happy then I guess I don't agree. **Edit:** Regarding the interfacing, I don't disagree but I don't think this is the way to do it.

Comment: @Script47: to be fair, I don't feel strongly about it. I do think we could do a better job of interfacing with other communities though, so... `:=)`

Comment: @halfer "I do think we could do a better job of interfacing with other communities though ..." Like asking reddit users politely to stop up/downvoting SO contributions just for fun? Not sure that would have much effect, but one could certainly try.

Comment: I agree it should be deleted, and for the reasons you said.

Comment: Also the argument of the fact a teacher found its own student doesn't even stand, the said teacher answered 1 year and a half later. Honestly I don't even find that fun.

Comment: The question doesn't meet our quality standards, so it should go. Period. Doesn't matter whether some other community finds it hilarious!

Comment: If the community wants to upvote it because it's funny, so what? That means for that one person for that one answer, they get a lot of votes. *And then the world ends, oh no.* You guys are all taking petty things so seriously lol. You really think that just because he got 200 votes for a funny situation now nobody's going to answer questions seriously anymore? I don't think you guys have thought this through much. Locking it is fine.

Comment: @Andrew you are now in the position where Atwood started in 2008. It took him about 4 years of observing how things worrk to [change his mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387205/how-should-we-address-the-i-assigned-you-this-homework-answer-shared-on-r-pro#comment711835_387205 "'we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site...'"). Are you interested in repeating his learning path?

Comment: Is it possible to just mark the original answer as the correct answer? Let the teachers' answer locked there (we have a lot of crappy answers on SO that don't get deleted each day - this one is at least funny) and the problem is solved?

Comment: @gnat I think there's a balance to be struck. The nuking answer below is an example of going overboard. If a person answers a question and puts a little side comment in, so what? If people are asking or answering questions with memes or silly stuff like that, that's obviously overboard. But for instance I enjoy it when someone posts a highly relevant, funny XKCD link, etc. These things make S.O. more fun and engaging to use, and also more genuine.

Comment: @Andrew ask yourself why would someone in their sane mind want to wipe fun out from their site. Per se fun seems to be absolutely great thing for site owners, it brings clicks, views, visits, popularity etc etc - then why would one wish to get rid of it? The only reason to drop it off is when owner observes with certainty how it brings so much harm to site content that it can't be tolerated

Comment: @gnat I think you read too much from his blog post. He wasn't saying he wants to remove fun altogether. Also, if he was, then I wouldn't want to use S.O.; you tell the slightest relevant joke in a side comment and some moderator deletes it? No thanks. Again, there's a balance.

Comment: '*If a person answers a question and puts a little side comment in, so what?*' - Imagine if everyone added their own little tidbit to all their answers, would it be a net positive or net negative? For that matter, what purpose does that "little side comment" serve other than as distraction? SO's concise nature is what rallies people compared to forums and their formats.

Comment: @Andrew '*Also, if he was, then I wouldn't want to use S.O.; you tell the slightest relevant joke in a side comment and some moderator deletes it? No thanks.*' - and that's fair, you're entitled to your opinion, not every site caters for everyone. SO's focus isn't a platform where you socialize, it's a Q&A site. If you must socialize, take it to chat(?).

Comment: @Script47 Well I've had people try editing my answers all the time, I reject like 90% of those attempts because they're being nitpicky. What purpose does the side comment serve? Are you a bot? There's a human, naturalistic, authentic element, and humor. Actually I would not say S.O. is popular because it is concise but because of its widespread involvement in problem solving. Many times answers are not concise.

Comment: @Script47 Yeah it's that attitude that makes me hate S.O.

Comment: @Andrew as I wrote [elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/839601) I use SO to help do my job and because of that I don't care if it's void of fun, all I need is it to provide solutions to my problems and this is only thing important to me. "If someone feels that the above sounds selfish, well, yes it _is_ selfish. I am in it because it helps me keep a nice job with good pay... To me, Stack Overflow is a tool. I use this tool in my job and I just need to keep it sharp." It's simple as that

Comment: @Andrew '*Well I've had people try editing my answers all the time, I reject like 90% of those attempts because they're being nitpicky.*' - You class it has nitpicking, the community classes it as removing "noise". '*Are you a bot? There's a human, naturalistic, authentic element, and humor.*' - But that's my point precisely, you're are coming to a site regarding programming Q&As looking for humor when it isn't supposed to exist here (not as a focus anyway).

Comment: I believe, this answer serves purpose. I genuinely tired of homework dump questions, so if this snarky answer deters at least 1% of homework dump questions to appear on the site, it's well worth it's upvotes.

Comment: I did not agree that either answer or question should be removed, look at the date it's asked on 2013 and this user suddenly earned a lot of rep just because someone put this in here in 2019

https://www.facebook.com/ProgrammersCreateLife/photos/a.241809332534619/2304820446233487/?type=3&theater

I did not agree this question and answer was a joke at all.

Comment: "Welcome, Redditors! We're looking for answers that provide serious, practical solutions to the problem stated. If you'd prefer to post a joke or launch a tangential discussion, please do so on the corresponding Reddit thread." I totally don't understand, why people think this question is a "joke"?

Comment: What's really weird/funny is that the answer was posted over a year after the question.

Comment: @jpmc26 I might be because the teacher see his student asking this question after a year and I don't see any reason why this question isn't valid

Comment: @User2012384 People think the answer/question combination is funny; see the associated [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/cauwnu/when_you_get_help_on_stackoverflow_from_the/).

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, the combination seems ridiculous, however, from the normal view, I think a student asked a question here and the teacher saw it after some time and decided to give a direction to the student, I think people are a bit overthinking here

Comment: @User2012384 How would the teacher even know the asker was their student over a year later? The question doesn't contain a problem description that looks like it was written by someone else; it actually asks a specific question. And the user name is user#######. The only indicator they're even correct is the fact the answer is accepted.

Comment: @User2012384 That's the point - the fact that it appears that a teacher came along and found one of his students asking about homework from his class, and then proceeded to post an answer, **is** what is funny (more like slightly amusing). The discussion here though is about what should be done with the answer now that it has gained so much attention due to the Reddit post, because it's not really a good answer, but it got a ton of upvotes just because it was "funny".

Comment: `echo that_question >/dev/null`

Comment: @jpmc26 the variable declarations in OPs question might be part of the assignment. If that's correct, and if the assignment was written by the teacher, this should already be enough to identify the OP as a student of their class - because even if another teacher created a similar assignment, the chance of them using the same words as input would be negligible.

Comment: Simple solution: undo all the votes that happened due to the brigading. Isn't the serial voting detection address these cases just as well?

Comment: I also think it's unfair to the OP cause due to this case, he suddenly not allowed to ask any more questions in SO. If you read his account history, he's quite new when he ask this question, why don't we give him another chance? You're all too harsh on the OP expecting a student 6 years ago to ask a very good question.

Comment: It's not fair to require a student to ask exactly the same quality as a professional and it's not fair to use the rules nowadays to apply to a question which was asked 6 years ago and result in the account was banned (due to too many downvotes)

Comment: @User2012384 to me it looks like totally fair expectation / requirement given that [tour] says, "site for professional and enthusiast programmers" (and not for homework cheaters). And it was this way long before the question was asked, not 6 but 11 years ago, since the very beginning of Stack Overflow in 2008 (with regards to the ban you seem to be mistaken, as far as I know it never happens because of single question - and I think old questions are either totally ignored for its purposes or have little influence)

Comment: @User2012384 Where'd you get the idea that the account was banned? It looks intact to me. As far as I know, the only negative effect of having a single question mass downvoted, closed, locked, or even deleted is maybe to *temporarily* prevent new questions, but even so, I'm not sure that's a valid concern here because the user hasn't posted any questions since **2014** and has never posted any answers (at least none that survived), so they're clearly not active in that way.

Comment: @Herohtar oh what I mean ban is that the user isn't allowed to ask any question due to a large number of downvotes received in a single question

Answer (score 111):

As the wise gnat quoted for us in the [comments:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387205/how-should-we-address-the-i-assigned-you-this-homework-answer-shared-on-r-pro#comment711835_387205)

> we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they need that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content...
>
> -Jeff Atwood, [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

The answer you link to truly adds nothing to the answers already provided. Worse, it adds less than nothing. It is literally what a teacher would tell you if you asked how to do something, not the kind of help we would provide here. Here, we like to provide clear examples and clean answers. That answer would *not* help any future users.

That answer is unclear and not useful. The only thing it says that is somewhat useful is to use "substring", but then you have to look off-site to figure out how to use substring if you didn't already know how! That makes for a very poor answer. Add to that the final sentence, which is very unclear, and you've got the "not useful" part.

It's also posted over a year after the question, how does this jokester actually know for sure that this is one of his students, and not someone with a similar coding challenge that isn't actually his homework? Perhaps this kid didn't *actually* already have a loop in main, because they had a different teacher. Even if they did, it's far too late to help them now, and being a smart-alec to your future students will likely just teach them not to ask for help, and not to search for it. That won't help our future programmers at all.

Not to mention, this just makes our site look like trash. Who wants to come to the site to find the answer to their problem to instead see a smart-alec answer like that, which doesn't actually solve their problem? Not only that, but it's upvoted to hell and accepted as the top answer? That's just wrong. We're telling future viewers that we approve of that nonsense if we leave that stand.

I say delete it. If we edit it into shape, we'll just be editing it to duplicate other answers, and, as you said, invalidating the author's intent. But if we leave it, we make ourselves look worse, and the site look worse.

Comment: *You* may think that the way SO is supposed to exist is to give people code dumps to their XY problems so then can continue on without even understanding what they're doing or that it's problematic, instead of having an answer that explains the problem and the approach that should be used to solve it.  But that doesn't mean everyone else agrees with that philosophy.  If you think explaining how to solve the problem rather than giving come code to copy paste isn't useful, you can reflect that with your votes.  That doesn't mean it merits deletion, or that others need to agree with you.

Comment: Downvote because: 1. The answer is not useful because the question is not useful. Not really the answerer's fault. 2. I would much prefer for a teacher to remark that he assigned it as homework than not, both for the lolz and to make people aware of it. Sometimes a little humor is good. 3. Actually I think that this question answer comments etc. make the site look more like trash than several of those answers combined would. Why are we even discussing this?

Comment: @Servy I didn't say a code dump. I said examples, but just to be better quality. How to use the code. Otherwise, I find it to be a poor answer. Full on delete worthy by itself, no. In this case, this answer literally has nothing going for it. It's poor because of that, it's also parroting other answers that are already on the question, _and_ it's confusing because of the last line. Gnat [actually shared another great post for the parroting part.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/2607247)

Comment: "Not to mention, this just makes our site look like trash." Um... what? I think most normal human beings would find the answer humorous and if anything- would result in them having a better impression of the site..

Comment: @chevybow We're dealing with everyday Stack Overflow users... I used them as the standard median, not normal humans. (As in, we've seen a lot of offense get shouted over little things before, and people get mad over snark and sass and "not getting helped", so why should this be any different? Not to mention we're here to make _high quality_ answers to programming questions. That ain't it.)

Comment: @Kendra I think there's a major difference between everyday Stack Overflow users and everyday Stack Overflow Meta Users. I think you're mainly describing the latter.

Comment: @chevybow Not really. I think there's a bit of mix between the two, but the whole "welcome" thing started from Stack Overflow users, not Meta users.

Comment: @Kendra If you think answers describing how to solve a problem rather than answers giving people code to solve that problem are bad, you're welcome to vote accordingly, but no, that *doesn't* justify deleting them.

Comment: @Servy That's exactly what I said in my comment? I find simply describing the problem makes an answer poor but not delete worthy, describing with examples makes it great. This _particular_ answer has more problems than just being poor quality.

Comment: @Kendra The answer isn't just repeating what the other answers have said though.  None of the other answers are suggesting what it is.

Comment: @Servy How is it not? The only thing it explicitly says that the others don't is the word "half." Is that what you mean? Because corsiKa's is sure using substring, so are the other two answers there. Come to think of it, _none_ of them are actually using loops in their answers. What am I missing, because I genuinely want to know?

Comment: @Kendra I think it would be best to focus on which type of users you want to attract or repel from the site rather than which type of users you are trying to accommodate. Some people shouldn't be accommodated. Also "high quality" is subjective.

Comment: @Kendra Other answers mentions substrings, yes.  None of the other answers are describing what the OP should be doing with it to solve their problem.

Comment: "Not to mention, this just makes our site look like trash" - I completely agree! Oh wait, you mean the answer and not the question?

Comment: @l4mpi Everything about the page we're commenting on here.

Comment: "Who wants to come to the site to find the answer to their problem to instead see a smart-alec answer like that, which doesn't actually solve their problem?" -- I do. Sometimes SO seems a bit devoid of humor; I'd argue humor makes a community more accessible, and the punch line here is funny (witness Reddit link). I'd wrap the response in quotes and explain. "One respondent wrote:... We don't vouch for the answer, but we thought it was funny so we left it. Students, don't post your homework."

Comment: More generally, while I think there's a lot of value in a culture of "by geeks and for geeks," IME people don't realize how offputting such a culture can be to those not on the inside. I'd rather have a community that's 99% pure and values the occasional joke than 100% pure and joyless. Just me; your mileage may vary.

Comment: @chevybow Who counts as a 'normal human being'? Do I? Because I think the answer is low-quality and makes our site look bad.

Comment: @TylerH Considering you spend all day on meta, no. Only on meta will you find people obsessed with eliminating any ounce of regular, sometimes light-hearted human interaction and reducing it to purely "professional speak". Because removing a 7 year old answer is the difference between a garbage site and the utopian site, in the eyes of the everyday meta user at least.

Comment: @chevybow OK, it looks like you're just making up a narrative to fit your opinion. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think it's totally unfair to CBGraham and user2150807. The question already stick there 6 years ago. By that time, people are allowed to ask homework question and after one year, the question was answered. The answer did provide an answer to the question itself and also provide future users that they have to use loop to deal with same situation.

Comment: @TylerH The answer isn't that low-quality: the answer provide a direction (using substring and loop) for the student to finish their homework

Comment: @User2012384 The answer spends part of its time repeating what another answerer has said (except in a more vague way and without examples) and the rest of its time being rude. It doesn't provide any value on top of existing content *and* is actively harmful due to the joke at the expense of the asker. That's... the definition of low quality.

Comment: @TylerH while I agree that the answer isn't great, especially from a "let's create a repository of useful content" perspective, you do not have proof that the answerer isn't actually OPs teacher. So calling it rude is an assumption (which might very well be true), but not a fact; and the answer should not be judged based on that assumption unless it can be verified.

Comment: @l4mpi Nothing I've said is based on or dependent upon any assumption one way or another regarding the answerer's status as OP's teacher. Whether the answerer is OP's teacher or not is irrelevant to the fact that it's making a joke at the asker's expense, and therefore rude (and also fluff).

Comment: @TylerH that's where my perspective differs from yours: if that guy actually is OPs teacher, then IMO that post might very well be the best answer across all of the dupes of the question _for the OP_ and certainly isn't rude _to the OP_. Because in that case it would simply be a statement of fact, and might even serve as a cautionary tale for OP. While it is structured in a way that sets up the "I'm your teacher" statement as a sort of punchline, that alone does not make it rude. But this might as well be a matter of personal opinion, and we both agree the answer is not worth keeping around.

Comment: @l4mpi When a teacher is rude to a student like that, we often call it admonishment, but it's still rude. Regardless, if the answerer is the teacher and what the teacher says is true, then the post can't possibly be the best possible answer across all dupes, because it would have been posted a year after OP *left the teacher's class*, making the response from the teacher quite useless. And yes, beyond the answer needing to be deleted, I moreso agree with others who've said delete the entire question, as it's lacking important context/demo code that already exists in other, searchable questions

Comment: It would appear the student knew that's the teacher.

Comment: @Joshua It's a high probability, given the accept, I admit. But, we can't ignore the possibility that the asker accepted the answer for comedy rather than a student-teacher relationship, either. Either because they found the answer hilarious, or because they thought accepting the answer would be hilarious.

Answer (score 82):

Here's a better idea than deleting or editing the answer: nuke the whole question from orbit. It has little value to begin with, and the actual programming task at hand is covered to exhaustion in duplicates like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353). If the crappy question is gone, the crappy answer will be gone as well.

I have no idea why a "please do my homework" question has gathered 40 upvotes (and only 25 downvotes) but a lot of these are probably due to the reddit post as well, as are many of the 80k views. None of the answers have an approach that isn't covered by an answer to question I linked (and I didn't even look at all the other related questions), so nothing of value would be lost if the question just disappeared.

Comment: But then the answerer would get to keep the reputation.

Comment: @JL2210 who cares about that? If you're concerned about somebody elses fake internet points, take a look at all the people who get to 2k rep by doing useless edits, or the ones with over 10k rep by answering obvious duplicates. Also, due to the daily cap we're talking about ~700 rep here, it's not like OP got instant closevote privileges from that post.

Comment: I think a poster only gets to keep the reputation if the post has survived for...60? days.  If it's deleted before that, the rep goes with it.

Comment: In general I agree, but... it's heavily upvoted content. I'm sure Reddit has a large part to play there, but that doesn't change the fact that our one and only quality indicator says "This stuff is sublime!". Until that changes, I wouldn't feel comfortable with deleting it all. That set a bit of a bad precedent.

Comment: If I typed up a question that I considered even half decent and it got "nuked", I would be pissed. Locking or similar is the proper way to deal with this, so there can't be any more votes, not so that the asker and answerers get the message, **"Your even being here was a mistake. We undid that for you."** See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/1599699 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/1599699

Comment: @Gimby I don't think your "one and only quality indicator" is worth much in the general case anymore. [This comment of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254129/do-users-upvote-out-of-sympathy-and-how-should-that-be-addressed#comment17747_254129) is more than 5 years old but more relevant than ever, as is [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254207/1110381).

Comment: @Andrew if somebody asking questions like the one under discussion here gets angry due to their questions being deleted (or closed, or downvoted - we have many people getting angry about that), I would not see that as a loss for SO. [Your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387205/how-should-we-address-the-i-assigned-you-this-homework-answer-shared-on-r-pro/387224#comment711979_387215) on Kendras answer fits perfectly here. Also, I doubt anybody involved in that question cares about it at all anymore, it's more than 6 years old.

Comment: @l4mpi That's where you're wrong. It does little good to piss people off unnecessarily, not to mention that that's unethical if you have better alternatives. If you *deter* a person from using S.O. or at least using it in a way the community does not want, that's one thing. But going further may result in: effects on the person in real life or those around them (i.e. at work), bad rapport for S.O., malicious retribution, and so on. Again, the key point I'm making here is that nuking would be *unnecessary*.

Comment: @Andrew people get angry due to all kinds of reasons, controlling that is not only impossible but IMO the attempt itself is unhealthy for the community (look at all the good things that came from throwing quality under the bus to accomodate the people raging about down/closevotes being so unfriendly). And regarding your tangent about people going postal at work etc, let's please remember we are talking about a _specific_ post that is over 6 years old, which OP probably only cared about until they got a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @l4mpi Not controlling it but doing the ethical thing which will seek to reduce it. We're not talking about a specific post but about a policy for how to deal with similar posts.

Comment: @Andrew First off, the meta question I answered here does explicitly _not_ talk about a general policy, but about one single specific question. The answer should be viewed in that context (and while I am of the opinion that more than 80% of all SO questions could be deleted without any value being lost, I would still advocate judging each of these posts individually). Second, I'm not interested in debating ethics with you but IMO, if somebody chooses to get angry about _X_, that does not make _X_ unethical. Not even if many people get angry about _X_. So I reject your premise.

Comment: That's not my premise but it's not necessarily ethical either, depending on what X is.

Comment: I don't agree with this approach. While the question is simple, I don't think that's enough reason to nuke it (or to make it close-worthy for any reason other than being a dupe). If it's a duplicate, then the right recourse is duplicate closure, not deletion of the whole question. If it's a duplicate *and* has a deletion-worthy answer, then we should handle those things separately, by deleting the answer and then closing the question as a duplicate - not by simply nuking everything.

Comment: @fbueckert Users keep reputation from upvotes on posts whose score is 3 or higher and have existed for at least 60 days (or is it 90?). It doesn't take into account, AFAIK, *when* the user gained reputation from them. So if deleted, the answerer would keep all the reputation gained (up to the rep cap) from the answer, even on the days where the Reddit Effect took place.

Comment: @MarkAmery main reason is that the whole post could disappear without any detriment to anybody. You assert that the ages-old answer is bad and we need to do something about it, which nobody would've noticed without reddit. And I say, all of it is bad, it's a bad question, so from a pragmatic perspective I would prefer just deleting the question instead of opening the can of worms that is deleting a genuine answer without a solid reason (you assume the answerer is not OPs teacher, but without proof - would your assesment of the answer change if I could prove it was the teacher?)

Comment: At this point, if the answerer loses the reputation, the answerer will be in the deep negatives.

Comment: @Joshua No, there is just a mismatch in rep/votes because the answerer hit the daily reputation limit several times -- they were getting votes, but no longer gaining rep. If the rep is removed the answerer will return to his original level which looks to be somewhere in the 300's. Also, there is no such thing as negative rep; the minimum is 1.

Answer (score 24):

Regardless of what we should do in this situation *in principle*, I believe this is a duplicate question and thus null and void. Since the question is on hold, it can't be flagged as a duplicate, but see [Insert a character in a string at a certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position) where the accepted answer shows exactly how to solve the problem in the question at hand (i.e. use `substring`).

Answer (score 18):

## Delete the question

The question is overly basic and a typical "How I make program do this?" question. The accepted answer is useless without the broader context of the lesson in question

> How do I know the loop is already in main? Because I assigned you this homework.

What `main`? **There's no code there**. As such, this answer is a huge joke. You can sum it up as

> You should do your homework the way I told you to do it and stop using Stack Overflow to solve it

Which means he's doing the same thing as [this frustrated professor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters)

> If you get caught, it is highly likely you will lose all the points on the assignment, and may face repercussions from the University. I know about this solution, and I have programmatic systems that leverage online solutions like these to find misconduct. You think you can get around it by changing comments or variables, or rearranging blocks of code, but you can't. I care about the academic integrity of our program; finding misconduct is my full time job.

While there are some serious attempts at answering the problem, they're not the main event. We could delete the answer, but the question isn't a good one and there's are better duplicates out there that describe the concepts involved with **actual code**.

Comment: I agree with everything after your heading and first paragraph. As noted elsewhere, I don't agree with the idea of deleting the question, because I think that - besides apparently being a duplicate - the question is okay. *"How I make program do this?"* questions, as you characterise them, are the core useful content on the site, and if this one weren't a duplicate, the other answers (besides the one purporting to be from the asker's teacher) would be helpful to anyone who came across this one on Google.

Answer (score 10):

I say that deleting the question itself should be fine, honestly. As many others have pointed out, it is a duplicate question.

However, I personally would rather prefer just the answer to be removed. It has earned that user a false reputation on SO, and I honestly can't really extrapolate anything useful, as its wording isn't as good as some of the other answers. If deleting the question itself doesn't delete the reputation of those who have answered/commented previously, I suppose it should be fine, but I am still concerned about someone having a high reputation because they were answered a question and said "because I assigned this for homework". If anything, they should have said something like, "come into my office this week and we can discuss a solution." That shows they are willing to teach, because I honestly think some things must be "spoon fed", such as basic sorting algorithms, and traversal through arrays. Because truly, once you understand the basic concept of what you're doing, then you can start applying it, and then proceed with more advanced techniques.