# This question of mine was closed due to lack of focus, but it shouldn't be more focused

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I asked (and answered) this question:

[What variations of vector-like containers already widely established? Do I have to write my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409337)

This was relatively well-received: 3 people upvoted the question and 5 upvoted the answers. The question is not focused all the way to concreteness. But - it is focused so as to be clear, and to afford the answer given, which is somewhat general and comparative. If I were to focus the question further, the answer would probably not fit.

However, the question was closed for lacking focus. Was I really wrong in my choice of degree-of-focus?

Comment: Upvotes are not a good metric to see if a question is a good fit for Stack Overflow (the [curl mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385542/7296893) comes to mind). I think the question is certainly on the broad side, particularly because it asks for 3rd party libraries too. And there are a lot of those. In my sector Rcpp is a common one, and it comes with 5 vector types. And there will be many more examples.

Comment: _"This was relatively well-received"_ Well, not anymore . Meta effect strikes again!

Comment: I honestly think that for questions like these one of the "worst" things you can do is post about it on meta. If the question was truly seen as "on-topic" by the community then very likely it'll continue to get upvotes and get re-opened "naturally", however, posting within an hour of it being closed doesn't even give it a chance to go through that cycle. As they say, patience is a virtue.

Comment: @Larnu: Lesson learned.

Comment: The (very long) title is asking for an opinion and the question itself is asking for a list... basically asking for offsite resources. It can use a little de-triggering.

Comment: @Gimby: Well, "should I roll my own" questions are in-scope for SO, and there are [lots of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=should+I+roll+my+own)... and are not really about off-site resources. Also, this was not my original title, but an edit someone made. How would you entitle the question?

Comment: Did you look at those results from your search @einpoklum ? That's is a vague search at best because it''s picking up any question that has the words "roll", "should", "my" and "own" ***anywhere*** in the question or answer. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428155/how-to-lock-a-channel-using-discord-py-bot/67429027#67429027) is nothing about rolling your own,

Comment: @Larnu: Ah, I forgot the quotation marks around the expression. My point still [holds](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22should+I+roll+my+own%22) when I add them.

Comment: 121 isn't many, if I an honest, @einpoklum . And 1 question with a phrase being on topic doesn't make another not off topic.

Answer (score 7):

> If I were to focus the question further, the answer would probably not fit.

I think this is kind of the source of the problem. You seem to be trying to reverse-engineer a proper SO question for which your answer would be legitimate.

But the answer is ultimately nothing more than a list of types provided by various libraries. Which means that any question is going to ultimately be:

1. A list question: asking for a list of things.
2. A library question: asking for one or more libraries that provide a thing.

The current phrasing of the question hides #2, but #1 is still incredibly clear. Especially when one of your options in the list you're asking for is literally "etc".

I get that you want to help people find a C++ contiguous container type that suits their needs, and that a single clearing house of such types would be useful. And I would agree with that in general. But SO is not a good place for that kind of thing. Sometimes, such things slip through the cracks, but by and large, they don't work well for this site.

Answer (score -3):

The question's answer has a positive vote balance and has been viewed quite a few times. I've encountered a similar question or sub-questions in real life and have sent people here. So, I feel that despite the list-y apsect, it's still rather legit.