# Very outdated blog post about the "new" release of ES6

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The latest blog post, [Does ES6 make JavaScript frameworks obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/10/does-es6-make-javascript-frameworks-obsolete/?cb=1), is about the "new" release of ES6 (a version of JavaScript) and discusses the potential effects of this event in the future tense. However, ES6 (also known as ES2015) was released in 2015, suggesting that this blog post was written back in 2015 before the release of ES6, making it very, very outdated by this point in time.

Accidental repost, or something else?

Comment: It also links to a post called “Companies Hiring JavaScript Developers **Right Now**” from 2017. Fwiw, ES6 has been around long enough and React/Vue/Angular seem popular as ever, so I suppose we can answer the question posed in the title with “no”.

Comment: This really does look like it was written years ago but never published, then recently 'updated' before publishing, as there is a link to a 2020 blog. It's a shame there seems to be zero quality control on something so prominent on the site

Comment: Actually, I find such retro-futuristic looks at things (where, usually, we get to read how badly mistaken the author was about projecting things into the future) to be quite insightful (as well as more than a little bit entertaining of course). More sites should present (or re-highlight) such articles, unironically (albeit with a clear disclaimer).

Comment: Even in 2015, I'd have been disappointed at the quality of this blog post. It's full of misunderstandings about what the libraries and frameworks discussed are actually used for, the sadly common "OO = classes" canard, the bizarre confusion over a language reserving a keyword before it was used.

Comment: Wait, people actually *read* the blog?

Comment: Horribly outdated information, misinformation... And to consider [tag:javascript] is the largest tag on the network. That's just embarrassing...

Comment: *"Wait, people actually read the blog"*...Apparently nobody responsible for managing the blog or site. It's a little unbelievable that the post is still up. (On the other hand, it's currently the most popular post, so maybe this is all just a psychology/marketing experiment).

Comment: So no answer on why it was posted? :)

Comment: @epascarello It's currently tagged [meta-tag:status-review] so I'd assume that means they're still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Not exactly. [[tag:status-review]] means that the moderator team has escalated the issue for review by staff. This tag puts it on the CM's internal issue tracker, which should allow it to get a response from them, eventually.

Comment: [SO tweetet out this blog post now](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1460273486044270596), doesn't look like they think there is any problem here.

Comment: @MadScientist ...well, SE aren't known to be the best at judging stuff. [Remember the curl question they promoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385542)

Comment: @CodyGray But regardless, that means there isn't an answer yet, right?

Comment: The blog post seems to have picked up an additional author today. It was credited to just Theodoros ‘Theo’ Karasavvas, but now cites both Theo and Ryan Donovan as authors. And it's picked up some strange edits: e.g. the 2nd paragraph tries to hide how outdated it is by now saying ES6 is "arguably the biggest change to the language yet" when it used to say "arguably the most hotly anticipated update to JavaScript since 2009" (the latter was arguably true...in 2015). But it's still fundamentally a puzzling embarrassment for SO to promote outdated clickbait content over quality.

Comment: Honestly, the edits make it worse. Instead of acknowledging the mistake, saying "wow, we shouldn't have published this" and pulling the post down, SO seems to have done a bad job of trying to hastily update it so non-technical readers might not realize how outdated it is, but anyone familiar with the subject matter still knows from the headline on that it's a bad hot take 6 years out of date. It raises real concerns for me about the future of the entire SE network, something developers will only rely on if it is high quality, that the company's content strategy is of such poor quality.

Comment: @ZachLipton Oh, that's rich. For reference, [here is the original version](https://web.archive.org/web/20211110173647/https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/10/does-es6-make-javascript-frameworks-obsolete/). The new one hasn't been cached by the web archive yet. The changes are slight rewordings in places to make it not sound like ES6 is in the future. Others are mostly cosmetic ones. All in all, seems like the blog team has learned from the dev team - just deploy to prod first, then patch.

Comment: Meanwhile, the author is assuming everyone is just "misinterpreting his writing"_"However, I feel like many of you are focusing on dates, and the newer versions of ES6 and miss the point of this piece. It’s a medley to ES6 and all the drastic changes it brought."_, which is ironically misinterpreting the criticism...

Comment: maybe if they just ignore it long enough it'll go away

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I spoke with the Content Marketing team. The author made some updates to the blog post. No additional changes to it are planned so I'm updating this to status-completed.

Comment: For those that are interested, here is [a diff of the post](https://www.diffchecker.com/vdjPr2kj) between November 11 and today (December 10).

Comment: Note that the post still has quite a few errors, ie. "ES6 ... is the most recent version of JavaScript.", "ES6 classes use prototypes, not the function factory approach ...", 
"... it was clear from the outset that ES5 was designed to support classes—in fact, the keyword CLASS was reserved. ", etc.

Comment: The issues with this blog post go beyond a few factual inaccuracies - the entire thesis of the post is a prediction which must have been made several years ago, and the thing which was predicted has not happened, and there does not seem to be any new evidence that it is going to happen. IMO the only sensible way to fix the blog post is to completely change the message to "X years ago I predicted this thing and it didn't happen, here's why I thought it would, and what actually happened instead" and maybe "here's why I still think it will happen anyway" or "so now I think it won't happen".

Answer (score 45):

(Note: Some of these were edited out of the post several days after it was posted. Other, equally obvious, anachronisms remain.)

To rule out alternative explanations, here is a selection of quotes which were clearly written several years ago, and the author hasn't made any effort to update:

> With the release of ES6 [...] many expect the same cycle to repeat again.

Not "the wide availability of...", the **release** of. That was 6 years ago.

> Angular and Angular 2

"Angular 2" was renamed simply "Angular" (with "AngularJS" referring to the previous framework) sometime between 2015 and 2017 (when version 4 was released), and is now on version 13.

This mirrors the situation of JS/ES itself - there has been a new version every year since 2015, so if you wanted to talk about what was supported by modern browsers, there is a host of *even better* features you could talk about. This is not even *hinted at* in the blog post.

> Ember and Vue and Aurelia ... Finally, a quick note about some less well-known, and less well-used, frameworks.

Ember and Vue were both fairly new when this article was presumably written, so may have seemed less popular. Both now regularly appear in lists of "most popular JS frameworks". (Aurelia does not seem to have made it to that category).

> This is the context, then, in which ES6 is being released.

Note the present tense; I can't see how to interpret this as something you could honestly write in 2021.

> In addition, support for ES6 modules in browsers is not going to appear anytime soon

This feature [is widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=modules). This is probably the most damning evidence against interpreting this as looking back at ES6 now it's widely deployed - if this was about *wider* support in browsers, what's this sentence doing there?

My initial assumption was that the article was posted by mistake, but some links do appear to have been added or updated. As others have pointed out, some links are from 2017 rather than 2015, suggesting this was "dusted off" more than once.

The only explanation I can think of is that someone has done an extremely lazy update on an old blog post.

It doesn't help that the blog post wasn't even particularly well-written in the first place. Maybe it was originally submitted and rejected, and standards have slipped in the intervening years?

Answer (score 4):

You must consider blogs to be what they are: unidirectional [opinion pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_piece) by authors whose credibility and authority you cannot validate.

The result is often suboptimal. Yes, some blogs have feedback mechanisms in the form of a comment box or a link to mail the author. Good luck correcting every blog author out there, and good luck getting your comment accepted on the Stack Overflow blog.

Feedback on blogs, and this particular blog, barely exists. We're shouting into the wind, with this question as well.

I'm not saying everybody blogs the same I (used to) blog, but in my experience bloggers usually write pieces to document themselves trying to learn something: *"this is my learning process, utilize it in any way you please"*. You have no idea that what you read is up-to-date, secure or even correct.

As for the "from now on we're not going to need frameworks anymore" stance displayed in the blog we're currently discussing, that's (checks notes above) indeed, suboptimal and incorrect.

Does JS already have native observables for two-way databinding? Commonly used UI elements like lightboxes, alert boxes that are not `alert()` and can ask for input? A decent HTTP client API (well at least that's one I know and can answer with "yes")?

So no, you're going to need libraries and frameworks anyway, to not reinvent the wheel.

> Accidental repost, or something else?

I think Stack Overflow just wants content on there. I think I've read somewhere they even offer money for having your blag posted there.

Comment: "*You must consider blogs to be what they are: unidirectional opinion pieces by authors whose credibility and authority you cannot validate.*" SO blog = Medium.com?

Comment: Given the posts that have been presented on technical subjects, i'd use a loose equal. "SO Blog == Medium.com." Medium does occasionally have great articles

Comment: The SO blog is just disappointing to me. When it was first announed, i hoped it'd be a blog with a very high standard on accuracy/quality. What we got wasn't that. It's somewhat of a great metaphor of the current Q/A situation.

Comment: @KevinB "*Medium does occasionally have great articles*" I want to be completely fair here and agree with you. I do not mean to imply that Medium.com is full of trash. There is a lot of it but mostly because pretty much everybody is allowed to write so, in effect, it is full of "authors whose credibility and authority you cannot validate".

Comment: Truth be told there is a lot with core javascript that you can do which frameworks keep yelling at you you need them for, but there are those key factors which you don't ever want to write code for again and which will make frameworks forever be the better choice. Validating and pulling data from web forms, for example. Or binding listeners.

Comment: @Gimby of course! A framework isn't magic, it's just a bunch of code. Whatever a framework can do, you can do yourself. It's usually just stupid to do so.