# Numerous errors in the recent podcast about quantum computing

Tags: bug, blog, podcast

The latest podcast (see the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/07/on-the-quantum-internet-data-doesnt-steam-it-teleports/?cb=1) about it, along with the comments under it pointing out mistakes) discusses quantum computing and what they call the "quantum internet". It makes a number of serious mistakes:

- Quantum entanglement does *not* imply faster-than-light communications. Quite the opposite, as creating entangled states requires the transmission of actual particles, which cannot move faster than light. There is no latency advantage to using any quantum technique to transmit data.
- Quantum key distribution still requires sending particles. They don't teleport. And they *can* be intercepted, but not without alerting both parties that interception has occurred.
- Quantum computers are not supercomputers - they are only faster at solving very specific types of problems, like those in the BQP (Bounded-error Quantum Polynomial time) complexity class. The vast, vast majority of what a quantum computer can do is irrelevant to most people.
- A read of a qubit is not simply a destructive read like that of a DRAM cell which must be corrected by re-writing the read value. It is called quantum decoherence and it acts on *all* entangled qubits, so the read must only be done at the very, very end of the computation (although a model called MBQC allows taking measurements during computation).
- Google's claims of quantum supremacy are hotly contested due to the contrived nature of the problems they claimed to solve. Only quantum computers with full entanglement between each and every qubit (or nearest-neighbor "fuzzy" entanglement) really matter.

---

This segment of the podcast should either be retracted, or an erratum correcting the mistakes should be published. There are a *lot* of errors and I can't think of how to rectify them without redoing the entire podcast (which is, of course, impractical).

Comment: "This segment of the podcast should either be retracted, or an erratum correcting the mistakes should be published." - if they did, they'd probably have to take down half the blog while they're at it. There's... a lot of errors

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I agree, but I couldn't think of any nicer way of saying "you're wrong, delete this".

Comment: Wow. People read/watch those things? I'm too busy downvoting and closing posts and crushing the hopes and dreams of n00bs with my toxic vibes.

Comment: Hardly an intractable problem, @Zoe. *"Disclaimer: Most of the content here may be inaccurate. For entertainment purposes only."*

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is that it _is_ inaccurate, not that it _may_ be.

Comment: @CodyGray "we highlight a selection of authors writing bad content for fun"?

Comment: They just [don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417731/many-syntactic-semantic-typing-and-style-errors-in-the-underscoring-or-dunde) [learn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412989/very-outdated-blog-post-about-the-new-release-of-es6), do they.

Comment: There's a nice hint in the blog's URL. The data may not _steam_ but the post itself does.

Comment: 1/ Your first couple of points are valid - everything about quantum computing is limited by the speed of light. However it's innacurate to say that they can *only* "solve very specific types of problems" - they (a 'universal QC') can do anything a classical computer can do *and* do problems outside BQP. Solving problems outside BQP will take an exponentially long time (and may suffer from technical problems such as requiring more hardware than available, just as a classical computer may be limited by e.g. memory) but *can* be done.

Comment: 2/ There *is* a model of quantum computation called 'measurement based' (MBQC) where measurements *don't* have to take place at the end. Google's QC (at least, the one they made the claim of computational supremacy with) *isn't* an adiabatic QC, rather a superconducting circuit model QC, although yes, you're right in that their claims of 'quantum computational supremacy' are contested

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 You're right. By "can only solve" I meant "are only faster at solving" (I'm aware of the Church-Turing thesis). I've edited my post to correct it (and your other points).

Answer (score 17):

Once again, the problem lies with the expectation that the blog contains things which are not garbage. As I said [one of the last times this came up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415464/1110381):

> The central issue here seems to be that you expect the SO blog not to contain bad content, or maybe you're expecting the people who write the posts to know anything of value about the topic they're writing about.

Just substitute "write" for "talk" as this question is about a podcast.

Given the prevalence of garbage articles along with stuff like CEO fluff-posts, it's clear that whoever controls the blog output has little to no technical knowledge. In essence, it should be thought of as an extension of the SO marketing department. As it's entirely controlled by the company, the meta community cannot do anything about it. Well, we can complain, but we already did that for many of the earlier trash articles, and it didn't change anything. Given that SO hardly listens to complaints about important issues, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for them to admit their blog "experts" don't know what they're talking about. Thus I think any time spent on lobbying SO to improve their blog is better spent on literally anything else.

So TL;DR: Yes, the blog contains a lot of crap. It's been that way for ages, we already complained about it a lot which didn't change anything, the probability of this changing is close to zero, and it's not like it matters all that much for the Q/A parts. I would suggest you simply adjust your expectations and assume that anything posted on the blog is worthless from a technical perspective.

Comment: They did actually take some action in [this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417731/5320906).

Comment: Even if you have technical knowledge, I don't think many people are qualified to judge a talk about quantum computing for technical accuracy. I'm impressed by Forest's rebuttal but I have no way to know if it's true or not. It's a lot and I don't know squat.

Comment: I'm by no means a quantum or physics SME, but I do know some basics; the first three points check out, at least with what we currently know about physics. The third one is trivial and usage rather than physics. Can't verify or confirm the other two because I have no idea, but I'm highly inclined to believe Forest knows what they're talking about. The problem remains, though; the blog and podcast clearly doesn't have good enough editors for the content categories they churn out. If everyone paid attention to find the bad posts, we'd probably be here several times per month with a new complaint

Comment: @snakecharmerb complaining may result in edits to the garbage posts, but only sometimes - no idea when they decide to fix or not fix things. And more importantly, they did not seem to have made any meaningful changes to their submission or verification processes to filter out the trash before it is posted.

Comment: @Gimby I didn't listen to the podcast (if I wanted to listen to crap, [Gutalax](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1971228-Gutalax) would probably be more enjoyable), so I'm basing this on OPs points. Some of those are basic knowledge for amateurs interested in quantum physics/computing, e.g. that an entangled particle must be sent to the other party classically before doing something useful with the entanglement, or that current "supremacy" claims are BS (e.g. the Xanadu "9000 years" claim is not about a useful computation, but about a supercomputer simulating the operation of the Xanadu machine)