# Does this question need a historical lock?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, historical-lock

I recently came across the question [How to identify unused CSS definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions) in SOCVR. Reading it, it does seem like it's a closable question.

I would probably choose "Needs Details or Clarity"/"Needs More Focus". One could argue that it is even opinion-based!

However, this question was asked in 2008 <sub>when I was like 2</sub>, and rules were very different. According to the [official FAQ about historical locks on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/500111):

> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> 1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic question, **and**
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, **and**
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, **and**
> 4. The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once.

Addressing all the points:

1. It needs a lot more focus. One might even say it is opinion-based, as it says "good approaches".
2. The question is a good question, even though it is closable. It has 416 upvotes, with a lot of views. It also has a lot of good answers (also heavily upvoted).
3. The post has been closed, reopened, and closed. There seems to be a fair amount of debate around its closure.

Lastly, I just want to bring up the reason why historical locks even exist:

> A historical lock preserves content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on

This question has arguably useful answers, with a lot of views, and a lot of upvotes. It was very popular when posted in ***2008***, but now it's just a closable question. I think this question deserves a historical lock.

I would also like to add that this question has not been closed and reopened *too* many times, but enough to qualify it for a historical lock. According to others, it also has a reopen vote right now, and may even accumulate more.

In the case that one argues it is *not* useful, sure. I am not an SME, so I will accept your word for it. However, a historical lock is not to preserve useful content, it's just to preserve content!

Think about it: Any question that was asked 10 years ago ***will have*** obsolete answers - the historical lock is to give the message that this question isn't okay, but back then things were different and this question was acceptable.

So, any thoughts?

Comment: Historical locks exist because the community sometimes can't agree about a question and pointlessly flip flops it from open to closed or deleted to undeleted in cycle after cycle. This is somewhat alleviated by the vote only once rule but nevertheless does still happen sometimes. Or as with the infamous zalgo answer they just can't help keep breaking it by editing it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Seems to be the case here? It certainly went through closing and reopening. Not the longest closing war ever, but enough to qualify for a historical lock. And plus, there's one reopen vote right now on that question.

Comment: 420 upvotes and only 3 downvotes - lots of users must have found it useful. So historical lock for the very least if it cannot be salvaged.

Comment: Many answers including the accepted one are near to link-only (NAA). Link in accepted answer is dead.

Comment: There are 3-4 answers with dead links; not useful anymore. A cleanup may be considered.

Comment: I wonder how one could make the topic more focused. Would it make sense to give some example CSS files with unused rules? Should one maybe specify a programming language/framework additionally and ask it for every possible language? I guess people want the problem solved and don't care, what tools are used. Or maybe it's one of these insanely complex topics, which even if focused to the maximally possible extent are still too broad for SO?

Comment: What about [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website) as was popularly suggested over 8 years ago? Not quite as popular but covers the same ground and, correctly closed and left closed years ago. Both questions are too broad, full of recommendations and out of date. Not sure if there's enough left to be worth locking for posterity.

Comment: @DavidBuck That question has been closed once, and that's it. A question needs to be closed and reopened at least twice, which this question has. I don't think that one is ready for a historical lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and locked it after pruning some old, outdated answers.

Why lock it? Because a great many of the answers are link-only. A former moderator closed it originally and nobody has made a solid case for a better answer in the last 12 years. The top answer needs to be kept, but we don't want to encourage more questions like this either.

Comment: If you lock a question, it should be because of the question, not the answers.

Answer (score 11):

The question is too vague/opinionated as currently worded (what counts as a "good" approach? What counts as cleaning up "a bit"?), and the answers are all just tool recommendations (which is what the question originally asked for).

Considering the myriad attempts to get it reopened by misguided souls over the years (check the question's timeline) and the fact that the one time it *did* manage to get reopened was due to some duplicitous circumstances (an edit for the sole purpose of bumping and advocating reopening), I'd agree that this question is ready for a historical lock, and I've already raised a moderator flag requesting that.

Comment: I'm unpersuaded by this argument.  Why should we put crap in resin?  How is it not crap?

Comment: @Makoto - Where is the flusher handle?

Comment: @Makoto The missing part of the puzzle is the little note on top of the post saying "Viewed 175k times". [Crap means traffic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books), so $tack Overflow must preserve all crap.

Comment: If an on topic question is attracting too many answers isn't that indication that it needs to be *protected*, rather than to be closed?

Comment: @user000001 First, protection is not for 'too many answers' (unfortunately we don't have an effective tool for that problem), and second, the issue at hand is not that the question is getting answers, but that it was reopened/getting reopen votes again.

Comment: @Makoto It's clearly historically significant as Lundin points out; 175k views over 10 years is a lot. The score of the question and many answers also indicate it's been helpful to a lot of people. As you can [now see](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/135657/revisions), the question is getting a lot more attention and reopening. A historical lock will prevent people from opening it or thinking of it as an OK question.

Comment: @Makoto I am not at all familiar with the topic, but let me say this - popular question, lots of upvotes, that means a historical lock. The question has got a lot more attention now. It has been reopened, and may even have a close vote on it (I don't have 3k). So an argument saying the question is useless doesn't really stand. It may be useless, but it was _popular_. 2 different things.

Answer (score 2):

No, because this is a matter of selecting sufficient tooling to help someone do the job.

Think of it like this.  Someone is coming into a mess and is asking for the best vacuum to use.  They specify that it's at least a dry mess, with lots of dust and soot, so there's no unreasonable ambiguity there.

The circumstance then is to go shopping for a vacuum that'll suit their needs.  That's...kinda the definition of what "too broad" was meant to encapsulate.

There's nothing of historical value to preserve except the myriad users who have come along with their recommendations for their favorite vacuum brand, and I don't think that's particularly valuable or worthy of preservation.

Comment: But the answers have a lot of valuable content. Even if it the question itself is broad today, and it won't provide much useful content today, back then it apparently did. After all, that's the definition of historical lock.

Comment: I agree with @10, if a question has 175k+ views and 416 upvotes (not to mention an up/ down spread of *418 to 2*), it certainly carries value to more than a few people, or at least *carried*, which seems to be what the historical lock is designed to preserve/ protect, regardless of perceived present value.

Comment: @10Rep:  How are they different from vacuum brands?  Use this one!  No, use this one!  No, use *this* one!  Like...what value is there *really* to extract from this?

Comment: @Makoto Because those answers provide _reasons_ for why to use this one. This is similar to another post that was recently historically locked.

Comment: @10Rep:  Those answers provide reasons why you should buy *this* vacuum.  It doesn't excuse the fact that the crux of the question is:  "What vacuum should I be using?"  **Unlike** the previous question that I advocated should be historically locked - the Git one - this particular shopper does not have a specific vacuum in mind, whereas the Git question explicitly stated that they have a vacuum and a floor and they want to be sure that they're not using the wrong vacuum head on the hardwood surface.  It's all about intent and scope, and this question is quite boundless.

Comment: @Makoto This question needs a _lot more focus_, fine. but the point is, it was very useful to previous people. It has a lot of upvotes. Such questions are supposed to be historically locked, according to the FAQ over at MSE.

Comment: @10Rep: The question isn't "*Was* it useful".  The question is, "Is it still useful *now*?"   What happens when those links break (i.e. a vacuum vendor goes out of business)?  Are the answers then capable of standing on their own two feet?  I would conjecture likely ***not***, because we're left with someone wanting to purchase this vacuum and being unable to, and being led here with a belief that this was an answer that they could rely on.  Upvotes *alone* don't mean a question is good.  I should know; [I have first-hand experience with this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto It doesn't need to be useful now, that's the thing. Because it was popular back then, which is why we have a historical lock. Regarding the past question, who even uses Git? These days it's all Github, no? That other question is also outdated, like this one, but it has historical significance. Broken links aren't much of a matter; they can be fixed. It may not be too useful today, but it was useful back then. Historical lock is to _preserve_ content. Any question that was asked 10 years ago will obviously be close to useless today. But we just want to presever it with a historical lock

Comment: And in any case, a historical lock just says, "This question is not okay to ask today, but back in the day things were different, and we just want to preserve that". It's just to prevent users from thinking that's an okay question because of the upvotes and views.

Comment: @10Rep No one is arguing more people liked it than disliked it. A list of the best xkcd comics would also be liked more than disliked. Doesn't mean it's fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @PasserBy It would have been fit back then, but now we would historically lock it.

Answer (score -3):

I don't see a reason for a historical lock, at least not yet.

The question was edited after it was closed, and successfully reopened.

Then a chatroom decided that it should be closed because it still mentions the phrase `good approaches` instead of `approaches`, so they closed it as too broad.

The community has begun the process of reopening the question, since it is an important problem in web development, that still needs addressing after all these years, and the top answers are on topic, direct and to the point, providing good and working solutions.

A historical lock makes sense when people are voting to delete good questions "just because they are closed". At this time, no delete votes have been cast against the question, and the required number would be quite big based on the upvotes, so there is no immediate danger of deletion at this point.

Comment: I am unpersuaded. According to the official MSE requirements for a historical lock, it only needs to be closed and reopened once. It doesn't need to be deleted in order to qualify.

Comment: And it's getting a lot more attention now. It's been closed, reopened, closed, reopened, and now it may even have a few close votes.

Comment: @10Rep: I didn't say that it needs to *be* deleted, but that the lock makes sense when it is *at risk* of being deleted, to prevent future delete votes. It's still possible to lock it, it's just that it doesn't make sense, as it can't be reopened or answered. Regarding the close/reopen cycles, these are due to the meta-effect, a 24-hour or 48-hour lock is enough. You don't want to keep questions locked without good reasons, because they cannot easily be maintained, so they will get outdated faster.

Answer (score -5):

OP mentioned "whole project" so an *acceptable* answer would recommend a tool or software. In fact, the second most voted answer points to a website that requires premium for "whole website".

Also, things have changed in the past 10 years and, as far as my experience is concerned (i) there is no reliable method of finding unused CSS (ii) nobody bothers saving a few kilobytes when we caching, CDN and compression are so common. Closing for whatever reason is OK.

Comment: When has recommendation for tools or software _ever_ been acceptable?

Comment: @PasserBy "Acceptable" for OP. Was I not clear enough?