# Revisiting our logged-out homepage

Tags: discussion, homepage

[image: tweets about the old stackoverflow.com homepage]

Today you’ll be seeing a few key changes we’re making in support of our new Free tier of Stack Overflow for Teams. You can read more about the story behind *Free* on our [Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/17/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-forever-for-up-to-50-users/) as well as the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever), but here I’d like to talk about the thought-process behind the logged-out homepage on stackoverflow.com.

### Community feedback

We revisited a lot of the [feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homepage) we got from the last iteration of the homepage we launched in June 2019.

Our homepage is typical of many large websites where the vast majority of traffic comes to other pages – namely those around asking and answering questions. As you can see in the image at the top of this post, visiting the homepage isn’t actually very popular at all, enough to be funny to even suggest such a thing!

However, we do know that there are still many out there who don't know much about us, so informing these explorers seems like a good function for the homepage. If you are reading this we are lucky you are probably most aware and engaged about what we do, but for those just hearing about us we’re trying to communicate what we do at a glance. We also know from talking to our customers that you might be invited to use Stack Overflow for Teams without ever having setting foot in stackoverflow.com, so we wanted to make sure we address newcomers about the context behind the product they are using.

Most feedback of the last iteration told us finding ‘Q&A’ was more difficult. We addressed this at the time by restructuring the URLs and reworking some language on buttons. In the version you see today, right up top next to search we present our call to actions before we get to the more information about the products and services. Everything below there is designed to be quickly skimmed and links out to find more information.

### How Stack Overflow for Teams fits in

We wanted to show how Stack Overflow for Teams, our primary paid product, was born out of our public platform and how the two are interconnected in our mission. We’re particularly excited for what our ‘free forever’ commitment means for how you use Stack Overflow within your work life or side project - they feel much closer together now that it’s free to start, so we wanted to visually show that. We’ve focused our design on explaining the value of and making it a much quicker process to create a team. We’ve also clarified that creating a team is creating a public Stack Overflow account (if you don’t already have one of course) - something that happened before but was unclear.

### Stack Exchange

Something we spend a lot of time thinking about from our brand perspective is how Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow relate to each other - we wanted to be clear that although you’re on stackoverflow.com, there is a whole network of sites you can explore from here. We’re highlighting a few of the related technical focused Stack Exchanges which might be of interest to a visitor just discovering Stack Overflow.

Finally as with all things on the web - this is just the latest iteration and it’s never ‘done’. We’ll always be tweaking based on how we see people using it and the feedback we receive. Thanks for reading!

Comment: For reference, [here is the logged out front page now](https://i.imgur.com/zPuwY4U.png)

Comment: heh, iunno if showcasing twitter feedback is a great look, considering the past

Comment: The majority of the page is still a teams ad

Comment: You know what - it actually looks nice. It certainly advertises Teams a lot, but a lot of concerns are actually addressed. The ambiguous text making it look like the public platform *content* is SE's achievement alone is no more. No vaguely "techy" images, a clearer distinction between info on public and teams parts of the platform, and a less aggressive color scheme (compared to the bright yellow to white. Still a giant ad for Teams, but I guess it is unavoidable. P.s. 2/5 tweets feel as if picked for a press-release. To make a point about it being unknown, the other 3 were more than enough.

Comment: I like the new design, but I don't like it much that people suggest that the rest of SO is not nice or welcoming. It's from 2019 though, so it might have changed.

Comment: Creating useful content is hard, people who have trouble doing so will always consider it to be unwelcoming.

Comment: @Trilarion Unfortunately, I don't think Twitter's perception is going to change on that (or frankly anything else it rages about) any time soon...

Comment: (unless of course we throw away our principles and give up)

Comment: Shouldn't System Admins have a tab open to ServerFault instead?

Comment: I don't understand the tweet posted about SO not being "dangerous", I've been here awhile and don't recall it harming anyone. Did SO employees show up at your house with bats or something?

Comment: @mxmissile someone was threatening to visit people at their home with a giant S.

Comment: So is Ads now #2 or #3 (behind Jobs) in terms of revenue?

Comment: Old-school coder here, and my first visit to the "home page" resulted in a knee jerk reaction that I'd followed the wrong link, and I closed it. Second view was "ok, this _is_ it, so _what is_ it?" So far my eyes have no place to land, no focal point to begin "exploring" the page from, let alone the site I think it's supposed to be about.

Comment: @Chindraba - that is actually a good comment - i would make that your answer and I would upvote it - this is a prime example that it is currently wrong.

Comment: @JonH This is the first time, and the last time, for me to see the logged out home page. I know I'll never direct anyone there, using instead some question as an anchor, with a strong suggestion to sign up before doing anything else. I don't link to ads, and that's all it is.

Comment: ... In fact, I have so suggested to everyone I'm familiar with that recommends SO. Including a few online instructors I know. I'll support SO, I cannot support that page.

Comment: Answers require 30 chars: _Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 12._, so short answer is "Rollback x2."

Comment: Are there any twitter reactions about the new homepage out yet?

Comment: *"right up top next to search"* does not read well. Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: At least as far as meta.SE goes - I had trouble finding feedback on the billboard-style landing page simply because a lot of this was in the midst of the troubles, and most of us kinda gave up on giving feedback the 'proper' way.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That entire paragraph has numerous issues IMO `In the version you see today, right up top next to search we present our call to actions before we get to the more information about the products and services. Everything below there is designed to be quickly skimmed and links out to find more information` i.e. also `before we get to the more info....`  and `links out...`  I had to re-read a number of times.

Comment: Even from a marketing point of view, this is a not a good homepage. Q&A is your product - why go to such lengths to hide it?

Comment: @Trilarion https://twitter.com/dbamastery/status/1372589287791759362?s=20

Comment: Ironically, [feedback on the previous redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391914/874188) would be a brilliant answer to this iteration, too.

Comment: @VLAZ: to see the current homepage, you only have to open an incognito window in your browser and go to stackoverflow.com - better than a screenshot :)

Comment: @rob74 works only until the next redesign. Then you wouldn't be able to see this page any more.

Comment: @mxmissile: _Rabid_ bats.

Answer (score 68):

Probably radical opinion: if SE wants people to know what SO is about, maybe create a route that redirects the home page to the [tour](/tour). It explains SO goals and how it's achieving it and the best of all: doesn't require anyone to try to come up with new ways to describe Stack Overflow. I think that using the tour as homepage is pretty neat. It doesn't show a list of questions, describes the product and how the product works. It even has an example of a Q&A pair!

Comment: Maybe something like a header "Wondering what stackoverflow is [ TAKE THE TOUR ]." and under it "Already using stackoverflow?  Use it at work!" marketing comes into play there.  Anyways +1 from me.

Comment: And how about onboarding users through asking a good question from the home page via a wizard instead of dumping them into the thick of things, and thinking it's enough to replace a wizard with the requirement that you have to click the 'post my question' button twice...

Answer (score 57):

I'm still not a fan. The main landing page is still a massive advertisement for the products that...hate to say it, but...the *vast* majority of users who come to the site aren't really interested in.

The feedback that you've pulled from social media looks incredibly hand-picked and curated, and its representation as feedback on a site who provided you *literally* orders of magnitude more pointed feedback is an affront to the whole feedback process.

The people that come to Stack Overflow are looking for an answer to their question.  The *original* landing page which showcased that was sufficient to get those unregistered users the answer they wanted and the value out of Stack Overflow that they required.  The other ironic thing?  If people are logged in or authenticated to Stack Overflow in any way, they'll never see it unless they intentionally choose to.

With this, we're basically still reminded that the point of this is to sell products to us.  Products that we're either not in a position to acquire or products that we're not in the market for.

But at least that [godforsaken curl question is removed from the front page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more#comment707085_386505).  Maybe now y'all can actually take the action to delete it since it *finally* doesn't provide you any value anymore.

Comment: I honestly disagree with your criticism. While "*the main landing page is still a massive advertisement for the products that [...] the vast majority of users who come to the site aren't really interested in*" may be true, SE still needs to make money to stay afloat, and this design revamp does a *much* better job of conveying the relationship between both components of the platform: the free one everyone is familiar with, and the paid one needed to keep the lights on. It's objectively more informative, both about the platforms themselves & SO's role in each, and that's a net gain in my book.

Comment: First thing I noticed upon clicking that link is "please don't tell that to Makoto". Why did it make me laugh?

Comment: @zcoop98:  The fact that they need money to stay afloat is *their* problem.  Why does that have to interfere with me looking for an answer to my question while I'm unauthenticated?  Besides, I've had several negative experiences in using their Teams product such that I cannot in good faith recommend anyone to use it.  I've had some of the worst interviews or call back experiences with it.  To be blunt I went *looking* for it.  I don't know why Stack Overflow feels moved to put it in front of our faces when we *aren't* looking for it.

Comment: @Clockwork:  Well, [the curl question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354) caused [a whole lot of fallout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354) from a then-very vocal and very angry Makoto...

Comment: @Makoto I fully agree especially with the low relevance of Teams for public Q&A users but still every month a 100k people or more open up a new account on public Q&A, so somehow people still find the way here. It could probably be better, but it also could be worse. Your answer reflects that nicely.

Comment: You know, the way you phrased the "money" part, makes me think about the second Sam Raimi Spider-Man movie somehow. That one movie where you have a scientist who work on a miniature self-powered sun, and a huge company is paying the bill. His work is his personal dream, and to the company, it's the pay check, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Trilarion:  "It could be better, but it also could be worse" is a characterization of a cow pie with whipped cream on top.  At its base, it's still a cow pie.  We haven't thrown that base out yet, and it kinda shows

Comment: Not exactly sure why you had to go and mention a post you want to have to deleted here. I don't want that post deleted.. I don't really care for anything else you said here. It's not important compared to you wanting to delete a post, that I think should be kept.

Comment: @Scratte:  Because it existed, the community did decide that it wasn't all that good (and to be fair, the post is actually on his blog instead so there's really not much of a point of keeping it here), it was *saved* by an employee here for dubious AF reasons, and then it was enshrined as a part of their sales pitch.  To say that this pours salt in the wound of any sensible curator on the site is an ***understatement***.  That felt like a thorough lashing with a Cat-o-Nine-Tails followed by a skinny dip into the Dead Sea, and those wounds are still pretty raw for me.

Comment: With the core impetus gone (and I can find some examples which indicate that the preservation choice was more of a marketing ploy than a community values ploy *later*), then deleting it would at least allow the wounds to start closing up.  It'll be tough to forget the actions, but at least the healing could start.

Comment: @Makoto The odd thing is that not all of us are so happy about the "delete it all"-path that some are using. We think it's a shame to delete all those posts, this one included. I can't see any other reason to delete the post than spite or hate for the post. I can't see it's harmful to keep it here. It's not harmful code and since it's closed it can't be used as a reason for another similar post to be posted here. Deleting it hides it from the world, but what's worse is that nagging feeling "I wonder what other stuff people have deleted on this site" and "Should I post anything here at all?"

Comment: "Delete it all" is only a thing because we've gone on for so many years now without deleting enough. The hole is only getting deeper.

Comment: @Scratte:  [Deleting it **absolutely does not** hide it from the world.](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/04/29/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/)

Comment: @Makoto Oh.. the irony ;) I do the same thing. Whenever I find a good post I copy'n'paste it into a file on my local system, because I *do not trust* that users will not just remove it from the site. Of course it's never my own posts that I copy, since I already know what's in those. But I don't put them on the web, though I probably should :P

Comment: Makoto, should we bury the hatched with a meta question asking moderators for its deletion?

Comment: @Braiam:  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - kinda feels like they owe us at least this much if they want to pretend to care about curation...

Comment: I still kinda feel like the curl question was [the duck](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2013/06/05/duck/) here; if that's all that was wrong with the homepage, then it was a pretty good homepage... But frankly, I suspect it was just an easy thing to fixate on, because design is squishy and requires thinking hard thoughts about utility and purpose. If the homepage is useful for some purpose, great... But if it's not, then the lack of a curl question doesn't mean jack. Maybe we start by asking if we could see intentionally sending a link to the page to anyone, for any reason, ever.

Comment: Money. money's always a reason to link to intersting things

Comment: I disagree; I think Q&A (though disguised somewhat as "community") and Teams here have equal footing, with Q&A actually edging ahead slightly by being on the left (at least for LTR languages...). I do think they should not obfuscate Q&A behind the "community" banner, though... it's unnecessary and we aren't really a community, ideally... just a repository of Q&A that happens to require human curation/input (until ML takes over).

Comment: Oh there was plenty else wrong with it @Shog9, but that was easily the last straw for me.   I'm sure that the feedback I've left here is somewhere buried in some tags somewhere about this front page, but I wouldn't really know how well absorbed that was *just* based on both this next iteration or the smattering of tweets about it.

Comment: I guess the actual goal was to create a new homepage that helps them make some more money out of their paid products, while at the same time incorporating some of the user feedback. So mentioning the user feedback first in this "question" is maybe a bit disingenuous - but OTOH, as others wrote, SE has to make some money, so as long as the ads for their paid product don't get in the way too much (like they do on YouTube for example), I don't mind...

Comment: @Shog9 It's not that the question link was easy to focus on. It's that it was a blatant demonstration of the fact that SO as a company no longer cares about the values that made it successful in the first place. It's very powerful evidence of the company's shift in focus to trying to have broad appeal and ring in more clicks rather than generating an objective information repository.

Comment: Ah... curl... that is one reputation point I don't expect getting back...but if I would get it back, that would be great signal that quality is back in focus here.

Comment: I remember when Makoto used to always err on the side of the company, and always emphasized "wait and see" and not get impatient with progress. Now Makoto is the exact kind of person 2018 Makoto would have complained about (not that I think this is a bad change, quite the contrary, though sad how jaded they had to become to get to this point).

Comment: @whn: At least I don't *think* I've ever outright complained or derided anyone who would complain about they disagreed with the direction of the site, but for certain I'm not the same person who believes that the company just needs a little more time or that patience is the right approach. I get the impression that the pain I've ignored or numbed myself to had finally reached its threshold and asking me to wait before the pain fades away was no longer in my best interests.

Answer (score 35):

> Most feedback of the last iteration told us finding ‘Q&A’ was more difficult, we addressed this at the time by restructuring the URLs and reworking some language on buttons.

There are 3 links to /questions. Two are perplexingly labeled "search", though search is available at the top and does *not* require or benefit from clicking these links. They likely suffice for folks who already know where they're going. I'm not sure they do anything for anyone else.

The core problem here is that this was and remains an afterthought. The purpose of the homepage as of the last redesign was to promote Teams, and so it remains; there's a stronger nod now to the primary use-case for the public site, but little or nothing to help guide folks who might be here for that purpose. Best-case for someone in that situation is that they find one of the links to /questions and arrive at the list of recent questions, with no further hint at how they might make use of tags or search to effectively navigate to the subset of information that interests them. For these people, the homepage is a no-op.

Because it was never intended to be anything else.

The biggest "calls to action" for the public site remain the signup links. *These* are what allow the reader to see actual guidance, the real homepage, and information on what sorts of functionality are offered for browsing. But they're calls without cause; only *after* clicking the button is any hint provided for what functionality is available via this path for *consuming* information:

[image: from the signup page: "get unstuck — ask a question Unlock new privileges like voting and commenting Save your favorite tags, filters, and jobs Earn reputation and badges"]

...and even then, it's part of a grabbag of other functions. The most basic use of the site - researching a topic - remains unstated, unguided, the entrypoint left entirely in the hands of Google and trial+error.

Because the homepage was never intended to guide anyone along this path.

So it remains a marketing page, an island unto itself, incongruous with the common experience.

Meh.

Comment: Tell us how you really feel :D

Comment: Honestly... I have a hard time caring at all. Only motivated to answer by Makoto's "curl question" discussion; I think it's important to focus on purpose, even if that purpose is super boring.

Comment: I think they could do better - seriously why not create a div with the top 5 hottest so questions for the week or something and throw it at the top...with some heading like Discover great questions...under this div the marketing could come in...like what you see, work in IT?  We have SO Teams...and throw some content of teams in there.  I dont know I like teams but I dont think they really need to sell it to me.  The selling piece is their developers getting teams to work right.  Is it perfect - no - does it help me yes so Im willing to pay for it.  I dont get why there is such a need to....

Comment: put so much emphasis on it...it ends up looking so desperate to sell.

Comment: Gonna come clean with you - I feel like removing the question would be the only thing that the company could hem and haw about and then make the painstaking choice to remove.  They've made their intention with the homepage of the site as unambiguous as gravity, and I don't see that...changing with feedback.

Comment: I'm not expecting any changes based on this discussion, @Makoto. All else being equal, change *should* require clear evidence that goals aren't being met, and that requires clear goals - and I don't think there are any, beyond "this should help Teams somehow". So many of these discussions - both here on meta and within the company - end up being pointless and stressful because folks go into them with differing hopes and unclear goals; recall the advertising fiasco from a few years back, where neither the company nor the community were clear on the desired outcome beyond "make money somehow"...

Answer (score 28):

Here is my issue with the home page:

> [image]

Out of this giant hunk of screen real estate, the red rectangle is all I care
about. That needs to be bigger, much bigger.

I get that you are trying to sell stuff, but you need to show **why people would
even want to spend money in the first place**. Behind that little red rectangle
is a decade of high quality content. Show it off. If people see the value add
of Stack Exchange, they will be more inclined to buy. To respond to a comment:

> Therefore, I'd think it's completely justified to not make Q&A the main
> feature on the page, since it clearly stands on its own.

People visiting the logged out homepage, may have **no
idea what Stack Exchange is**. This could be the case, even if they have used
the Q&A part already. Stack Exchange needs to utilize the home page, in part, to
say "hey, you know that awesome question site youve used before (BIG LINK TO IT
HERE), well, we also sell stuff!".

If you can link the positive experience people have had with the Q&A to paid
products, I think its a good move. Otherwise people may not make the connection
on their own.

Comment: The only counter I'd raise to this is that SE already acknowledged that most newcomers to the site don't even arrive at SO/ SE through the home page, but through the Q&A outright ("*Our homepage is typical of many large websites where the vast majority of traffic comes to other pages*"). Therefore, I'd think it's completely justified to not make Q&A the main feature on the page, since it clearly stands on its own.

Comment: Solid rebuttal, I think you have a good point; I appreciate the response. I do still believe the new design is a marked improvement over the old page, but I very much agree that it also still fails to "*link the positive experience people have had with the Q&A to paid products,*" as you put it so nicely.

Comment: @zcoop98 "*The only counter I'd raise to this is that SE already acknowledged that most newcomers to the site don't even arrive at SO/ SE through the home page, but through the Q&A outright*" I have no intention to counter that because it's undoubtedly true. *However*, most people who arrive through search hits also aren't here to explore the site. Of the people who decide want to explore and maybe learn more than the current Q&A they are looking at, a lot are probably going to head to the home page. Yes, that's a smaller percentage but it's also the group that the home page should cater to

Comment: I agree with the "show it off" point. Perhaps onebox the *Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?* post somewhere in there even.

Answer (score 24):

> Most feedback of the last iteration told us finding ‘Q&A’ was more difficult, we addressed this at the time by restructuring the URLs and reworking some language on buttons.

I don't see this being substantially addressed. This is not about some words on some buttons. Stack Overflow is all about questions. Nothing gives a better idea of what it is about than *seeing* those questions.

Have you considered simply showing a *live* preview of these in the initial viewport? Not just some screenshot of outdated questions, but something that people can immediately interact with? Maybe the most interesting questions of the last 24 hours?

[image]

Comment: IIRC the old version sortof did this, but with a Q/A pair that was blatantly off topic.

Comment: It could be a live version - maybe not the most recent, unanswered questions but somewhat well-received questions from today.

Comment: There's this amazing real-time feed of questions built for exactly this purpose... https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime

Comment: +1 because this is exactly what I was thinking, right before I encountered your answer.

Comment: Would it be useful to invite visitors to explore tags they are interested in? Like "Here are our top [python](/tags/python) questions, and our top [javascript](/tags/javascript) questions, and our top [php](/tags/php) questions (bless your wretched soul)"?

Comment: @Shog9 - Uhm, what? How did I never know about that. That would fit perfectly there.

Answer (score 17):

> we wanted to be clear that although you’re on stackoverflow.com, there is a whole network of sites you can explore from here.

It is certainly good that there is something pointing to the rest of the SE sites. That being said, anyone who actually finds the link to the SE network deserves a cookie. I missed it 3 times in a row, and **I was actively looking for it.**

It is yet another color block with text at the bottom of an endless page of color blocks and text. It is *after* links to advertising and jobs. Why would anyone keep scrolling down? This is the same as putting it behind a sign that says, "Beware of the leopard".

> We’re highlighting a few of the related technical focused Stack Exchanges which might be of interest to a visitor just discovering Stack Overflow.

Are you? If so, I missed them.  Actually, I see them now. You are talking about the random icons that appear on the screen around the Stack Exchange area. There is no hint at all that I should randomly click on icons that are not descriptive at all. These would be much more discoverable if there was text to go along with them.

Comment: "who actually finds the link to the SE network deserves a cookie" it was a drop down from the icon at the top left.

Comment: Well, after reading this answer - twice - I did find the link. Sort of anyway. I scrolled too fast, however, and was gone before the "random icons" appeared, so I was confused by that section of the answer. Third time, while looking for the "icons" I noticed them start to appear. That they are links is about as apparent as the sun rising in the west.

Comment: @Braiam What drop down? The hamburger menu? Not there. The "Products" tab? Not there. The only link that I can find to the rest of the StackExchange network sites is at the very bottom of the page, just above the footer.

Comment: [Reference for *"Beware of the leopard"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnI62dsOKDo&t=9m48s).

Comment: "From serverfault to superuser" - .... that's the second and third topical site to be established :D

Comment: @hazzey look for the supercolider™ on MSE. Or discussions about the top bar after that.

Answer (score 16):

I'll tell a story.

Recently I was talking with my non-programmer colleague about contributions to humanity. And I told him that I am helping other programmers of the whole world sometimes using StackOverflow. He seemed to be intrigued, so I told him to type "stackoverflow" in Google, click it and ... **10 minutes** later I was able to reach the Q&A part to show him what I was talking about. I felt like an idiot and a liar.

That landing page is crap. It's annoying, overcolored, ugly, distracting, useless, not to the point and looks like a result of work of typical *effective manager* who has 0 relationship to a programming, but a very good at selling people furniture.

It's not an additional click, rather an additional time cost to anyone before they are *at site*.

Please remove it.

Comment: Maybe they did something based on your feedback, but the first two places I tried to click both worked, and brought me to the questions.

Comment: @tripleee, just tried in incognito and nothing seems to be changed. Whatever I click it will either send me to a register page, to some teams pages or does nothing. It could be I am an idiot though or perhaps too old?

Comment: Maybe I'm not a good test subject, in that I sort of guessed that the thing which is labelled "search content" actually doesn't (it's in small type so I probably didn't even read it properly). The second thing I clicked on was the big Stack Overflow planet image; the image itself actually isn't clickable, but moving the mouse slightly and trying again fixed that for me. Perhaps the main image should also be linked?

Comment: To sell a thing they should not be blocking the entrance completely. Users like me hate clicks, we basically leave the new site completely after seeing the first popup window. And while SO would be hard to replace there are many SO Teams alternatives. Recently they "refresh" their SO Teams ad (which present on many pages anyway), so it popup-up again to tell me it's free. I hope all they are doing is really worth it, it works opposite for me: I will **not** recommend SO Teams to anyone and will try my best to avoid using it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's messy and somewhat repellent.

Answer (score 15):

This is not the first answer to point out that the questions are hard to find, but since the first time the questions were hidden, I've always found it to be a perplexingly, *amazingly* bad decision. Imagine a popular grocery chain, and imagine going to their site and getting... the company presentation. The brochure stuff, for historians or investors. Imagine, amidst claims of "thousands of locations countrywide" and "a wide assortment of household wares", having to hunt around for the link to find the stores and opening hours and locations, or to the web store where you can buy stuff for delivery.

It's not that it's a poorly built web site, it just doesn't fulfill the goal of *letting people who go there do what they probably want to do*, which is to do stuff with the actual questions. Have this site available somewhere under "what even is this thing" and let the real questions site itself do the talking; the box at the top about questions and answers that was there for a few years did a good job on its own and led to the tour page which is a great way of explaining in simple, direct and relevant terms how it works and which subjects this Q&A site covers.

Comment: Unfortunately lots of websites are making it very hard to find out what their product is really about. Stack is no different. I can't count how many times I've given up on finding out what a product is about from their own website and instead gone to find out through wikipedia. Admittedly I'm less likely to use a product if the company can't even present or explain it on their own site.

Comment: Exactly - it may be the case that Stack wants the visitor to be interested about other things too. But accosting them when they're trying to accomplish something isn't productive.

Comment: This argument is a good one *only* if most traffic to SO was routed through the home page. As far as hard numbers go, we have this [Overflow Blog post from 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/), which says that, at the time, *less than 1%* of unregistered user traffic hit the home page. There's no reason to believe this number has increased in the time since then. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] This matters because it helps illustrate the page's purpose- when I go to Target.com, it's because I want to search Target for products. When I want an answer on some programming question, I *search Google*. Posts from SO naturally float to the top of results because they're useful and relevant. This isn't true of a store, which makes it a poor comparison. The home page is an ad pitch because it doesn't need to function as a funnel for new users to the rest of the site; that isn't its purpose, and thus isn't its design as a result.

Comment: This reminds me of the [one in a million is next Tuesday story](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/one-in-a-million-is-next-tuesday). Of course Stack Overflow receives most traffic from search engine results going straight to questions. But 1% (or less than 1%) of Stack Overflow's traffic is still many millions of visits, magnitudes more than most other web sites, and still a whole lot of people to leave confused wondering what's so great about this site that they can't even find their way into.

Comment: Or in other words, I'll bet you any amount of money that the vast majority of visitors to stackoverflow.com are more interested in ending up among the questions than in ending up in the other site.

Comment: @zcoop98 Re "doesn't need to function as a funnel" it doesn't matter what percent of Q&A seekers arrive at the page. What matters is what percent of people who arrive at the page seek Q&A.

Comment: @zcoop98 Of course if you want to maximize corporate profit then you are interested not in people who seek Q&A but people who might buy product. But get the costs & benefits & reasoning right.

Comment: @philipxy For sake of argument, it's also important to flip your point on its head: What *also* matters is what percent of people who arrive at the page do indeed seek to buy Teams, a number we don't have. If some insignificant percentage of people that end up on the home page *are* seeking to buy product, then the page works exactly as intended.

Comment: @zcoop98 You seem to be restating my 2nd comment. PS Maybe irritating the great majority of people who arrive, Q&A seekers, who have some indirect benefit to the company, should not be totally ignored when determining "as intended".

Comment: @zcoop98 People seeking other information than the questions is a legitimate point, and I think Teams is a big chunk of those (as are companies looking to advertise directly on Stack Overflow). There is a highly visible, clear and well designed "Stack Overflow for Teams" promotion in the left sidebar, and there's plenty of room for more such information without crowding out or outright hiding the main use of the site, including a link throwing to the other site.

Answer (score 13):

This new front page seem a definite improvement over the last couple iterations. It places public Q&A in a more obvious and visible position, and in a way that clearly shows how teams flows from and relates to the public Stack Overflow platform.

One suggestion I would make would be to swap the positions of the "Join the community" and the "search content" buttons. While I do understand the impulse to get users to sign up, the first use case most people have is searching for content on Stack Overflow. As such it feels like search should be the more prominent button, and the one the eye is naturally drawn to. Furthermore, if someone is not already familiar with what Stack Overflow actually is then the login screen probably isn't the best introduction to what we do here. Taking them to the questions list however will give them a much better idea of what the site is really about, which seems more likely to keep them interested than the account creation process.

Comment: I think it's a bit interesting that the signup page says "Get unstuck — ask a question"; probably not a good idea honestly. Really should be something like "Get unstuck -- search Google for our questions". Kind of kicking the can down the road here, SO set out to be a "definitive collection of coding questions & answers", after 10 years, surely they made some progress on this? By now SO is pretty much that for all but the newest techs and niche problems, in that case wouldn't it be better to present the information SO already has, somehow? There's no real strategy for this, which is kinda sad.

Comment: I guess what this page is saying is, 1 on 1 help is more .... profitable? than making a reference, does that mean that SE thinks that it's more cost effective to target users with one on one help (does not scale at all) instead of targeting users that would rather search and read? Or are they thinking that the readers and searchers are already well served and it's time to pivot to explaining the content that's already here? As somebody who reads I see a lot of outdated/flawed content, so there's still some problems to solve there. A better search would be a big step towards discoverability.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not the target audience for the SO landing page, but I still find the whole thing incredibly confusing in terms of navigation. This is not on the landing page alone, especially the company pages help with the confusion here.

What I don't get from the homepage and the entire navigation is a sense of how the site is structured. I know that there are the following big sections:

- Q&A
- Teams
- Jobs

And then there are some company sections that are for a more limited audience

- Company/About
- Blog/The Overflow
- Advertising

The product dropdown does the best job to show these, but I still find that one a bit confusing for someone without any previous knowledge about the company. But the other parts of the homepage make it even more confusing.

Q&A and Teams and Jobs are intertwined, which is to some extent understandable, but also a bit confusing. And Teams is really two parts, the actual Teams interface inside Q&A and the Teams landing pages for selling you Teams.

The moment where it gets really confusing is if you click on any About or Company page. Suddenly the top navigation changes entirely, in a completely inconsistent way to the main SO site. God help anyone that clicks through to The Overflow, the way back to the homepage is quite unobtrusive there.

Another issue is what "home" means in each section. For anonymous users this leads far too often to the landing page, not the main section they're actually looking at like Q&A. If you arrive at SO via Google on any question, if you make the mistake of clicking "Home" or the logo in the top left, suddenly you're in what looks like a very different site altogether.

Comment: That last line is a good point that I haven't seen much of, it doesn't *look like* Stack Overflow. The main part of the site is relatively minimalist and functional, which at least for me personally is exactly what I want in a Q&A site, and then you get to that mess of a homepage that feels like it's trying to incorporate every single modern design trend just for the sake of being trendy.

Answer (score 11):

Couple of observations. I'm not a UX designer or a webdev so please take whatever I say with a grain of salt

[image]

We have a search bar on top. Both the 'calls to action' on the top are for new sign ups. It might be nice - instead of having an inconsistent "search content" to point it at the site tour or "Discover Stack Overflow" to match the tour teams has.

The page is *incredibly* deep and has elements popping up at me. Its shiny but slightly distracting.

On my UHD screen I need to scroll *about* 4 page-downs to see anything about teams, 6 for other products and 8 for the wider network. There's no 'short' way to get to a specific thing if I want to. On the teams page its 2. Might be nice to have some way to skip down to "Yes! I want to just get the thing! Cut the sales pitch!"

Comment: Was going to add a post about "search content" being misleading asking to change it to "browse content".

Answer (score 11):

Suddenly, I have this thing on the left of **every single Stack Exchange community** for which I am either not logged in or don't have an account:

[image: Small tag sticking on the left of the page, advertisement for "Stack Overflow for Teams"]

I don't know how to describe it, but I personally find it... unpleasant? Distracting?

It doesn't help that it looks like a black square on top of a (most of the time on most community) clear background, and it keeps following me as I scroll down.

If there was a cross to close it, I would have clicked it. But for now, I will use µBlock to zap it out of the way.

Comment: That's weird, mine had a cross to close it, and it hasn't come back since.

Comment: Just Adblock that whole section, it’s only ever used to advertise garbage

Comment: This is explained in [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever)

Comment: I find it more distracting that Ask Ubuntu and Super User flies a big cookies banner across the useful content every single time a page loads. Probably something in my browser config (NoScript and what not) but seriously, it should just go.

Comment: As @zcoop98 mentions mine, while being logged in, [had it too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaXGU.png). Then I clicked the little X and it's not been back since. Now I'm left to wonder how I get it back :D

Comment: @Scratte Now that you mention it, I think I probably had the bar on the left too a long time ago. And now it stopped showing up when I'm logged in, although it keeps showing up when I go to some communities on which I don't have an account. That last bit is what I find strange, why would people be interested in having Stack Overflow for Teams if all they want is to read stuffs on the Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange community?

Comment: @Scratte Actually, I had checked the "Hide left navigation bar" in my settings. I just unchecked it, and now I see what you saw. And yeah, once I clicked the cross, it left forever, on every communities. I think there's 2 things going on here: there's an account specific setting, and there's a cookie too for the communities where I don't have an account.

Comment: @Clockwork Maybe some people feel like "Beer, Wine & Spirits" is best as a team-effort? :D

Answer (score 5):

Awesome. I really am a fan of the new design.

I think that there is a better word choice for making it to the public Q&A section though, instead of "or [search content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)".

I am unsure what a better fit would be, but searching content isn't exactly a welcoming phrase, it is insider jargon.

- "or browse questions"
- "or see new posts"
- "or view for free"
- "or start looking"
- "or view content"
- "or step right in"

Or none of those, but something other than search content, which to me, I picture a search bar, not a full fledged 100% free access to the most awesome knowledge repo on the internet.

Comment: "or get the Tik for your Tok" to connect with the younger target audience ...

Comment: I must be the only young adult who doesn't use Tik Tok...

Comment: @10Rep Don't worry, you're not the only one to be yourself. I don't drink, I don't smoke, I don't use Facebook, Twitter, TikTok, WhatsApp, Instagram, I rarely use my phone, I don't hang out, I don't use Signal, ... I am myself, and I use stuffs I like.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow is a community of developers. Developers know this and have helped shape and grow the site to what it currently is today. It is a no nonsense interface useful for Q&A, period.

The parent company is just trying to capitalize on this "crowdsourcing" of sorts by introducing corporate bells and whistles. I participate on Stack Overflow because as an individual I feel unique regardless of the company I am working for. Stack Overflow rep matters not in any interview process I've been a part of.

You can bet your bottom dollar that if my upper management ever got suckered into what's going on here then I would make a new account.